# No PHP, NULL é uma constante ou uma palavra-chave?

Tags: php, null

No PHP, `NULL` é uma constante ou uma palavra-chave?

Já ouvi dizer que é uma constante, porém parece com comportamento das palavras-chaves do `PHP` (que não diferenciam maiúsculas de minusculas)?

Exemplo:

```
echo NULL;

echo null;

exit('teste');

EXIT('teste');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NULL` é um tipo segundo a documentação [Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.null.php) e também é o único valor possível do tipo `NULL` (confuso mas é isso que esta na documentação)

Então pela documentação pode-se verificar que NULL é:

- um Tipo.

  > NULL é o único valor possível do tipo NULL.
- uma constante.

  > ela foi assimilada com a constante NULL.
- um valor.

  > NULL é o único valor possível do tipo NULL.

Comment: Eu sei que pode parecer polêmicas algumas perguntas que faço, mas faça esse teste

`var_dump(array_key_exists('NULL', get_defined_constants()))`. O resultado é `TRUE`

Comment: Só pra descontrair `TRUE` e `FALSE` também são constantes, kkkkkk

Comment: Não realmente é bem confuso e ambíguo

Comment: `NULL` é uma constante com o valor `NULL` que é do tipo `NULL`. :P

Comment: @WallaceMaxters muito bom o exemplo, isto é muito útil para obter o resultado.

Comment: Se você usasse o `isset` ao invés de `array_key_exists`, retornaria `FALSE`, pois o `isset` verifica se existe a variável e se ela é `NULL`. (espero não confudir ninguém com essa colocação)

Answer (score 2):

Só complementando a [resposta do @ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74867/8493):

#### [Palavras-Chaves](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.keywords.php)

> Algumas representam coisas que parecem funções, algumas parecem constantes mas na verdade não o são realmente: elas são construtores de linguagem.

**Exemplos de palavras chaves:**

- abstract
- and
- as
- break
- case
- try
- catch
- const
- continue
- default
- new
- echo
- else
- elseif
- for
- foreach
- function
- global
- instanceof
- private
- protected
- public
- static
- return

Algumas que também são (mas que na verdade parecem funções)

- die()
- empty()
- isset()
- unset()

Para conhecer todas acesse a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.keywords.php).

Answer (score -1):

NULL em php é um tipo que representa a ausência de valor, em algumas linguagens é representado por NIL!