# O que realmente significa NULL?

Tags: característica-linguagem, terminologia, null

Muitas pessoas falam sobre o que é NULL, mas afinal, qual é o seu verdadeiro significado?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2407/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-null-e-undefined

Comment: [Null em banco de dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/91)

Comment: @Duds, `NULL` é `NULL`. Brincadeira

Comment: "Muitas falam sobre o que é NULL" muitas o que? A propósito, você retirou as tags de linguagem, mas deixou `caracteristica-linguagem`, fica meio difícil responder assim no abstrato (já que linguagens diferentes tratam `NULL`, `null` ou `nil` de forma diferente), você quer uma visão geral sobre o conceito (i.e. uma resposta mais "filosófica") ou quer saber a aplicação prática em algum contexto específico (ex.: linguagens de programação vs. banco de dados).

Comment: Eu quero uma definição mais "filosófica" @mgibsonbr, NULL nunca ficou tão claro pra mim antes

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74866/no-php-null-%C3%A9-uma-constante-ou-uma-palavra-chave

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2296/215

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> A pergunta foi editada quando já existia várias respostas, inclusive esta que era a mais adequada ao escopo inicial dela. Ela ainda é válida, mas preciso colocar isto para os que não entenderam porque estou falando de Java e C++

`null` em Java, ou `NULL` (em C e C++ no estilo antigo) ou `nullptr` (C++ moderno) é a indeterminação de um valor. No contexto da pergunta ele sempre é representado por um ponteiro valendo 0, ou seja, apontando para um endereço que foi convencionado inválido na memória. Assim o código sabe que não pode acessar nada.

Neste contexto o `null` tem um valor, como indicado acima. Mas ele não aponta para um objeto válido que deveria ter um valor significativo para o tipo que ele representa. Ele indica que não há um objeto correspondente para aquele valor.

Null não é um tipo nessas linguagens, e também não significa ausência de tipo. Ele pode ser um tipo em outras.

`null == null` e é diferente de todo o resto (nestas linguagens).

Obviamente tentar acessar alguma coisa no objeto que deveria existir em uma variável com valor nulo produzirá um erro, já que não existe nada lá para acessar.

Em outros contextos, ele pode ter uma definição mais específica e um pouco diferente desta.

Em SQL, por exemplo, só indica a indeterminação de valor. Não tem nada dessa coisa de memória, outro objeto. Alguns dizem equivocadamente que é nada, ou ausência de valor, mas isto não está correto. Há casos que as pessoas usam o nulo para dar alguma semântica específica e dizer que é "não aplicável", "não existente", "não definido", ou algo assim. Mas isto é algo específico para a aplicação.

O Null pode ser só o terminador de *strings* no padrão C (o padrão de *string* mais usado). Ele é usado porque é um caractere inválido em qualquer texto.

Outras ["milhões" de definições podem ser achadas aqui](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WhatIsNull).

[Uso em outros contextos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null).

Ele é chamado de "[o erro de um trilhão de dólares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions)" (ok, eu atualizei os valores, o original fala em bilhão)

Null não é a mesma coisa que [Null Object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88741/101).

Linguagens modernas estão evitando o seu uso, pelo menos por padrão.

É comum ele quebrar a tipagem estática e segurança de tipo das linguagens que pregam isto.

Leitura auxiliar: [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)

[image: 0 X NULL]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Uma coisa que não significa nada na linguagem tem tantos significados, rsrsrs

Comment: -1 porque eu só achei 30 definições sobre o que é 'null' nesse link que você passou :D

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio só espero que as pessoas sejam tão bem humoradas quanto você e não leia isto e negative mesmo :D

Comment: +1 pela citação de ponteiro 0 na memoria = D

Comment: +1 - perfeita descrição técnica.

Comment: Lembro de dois programadores C++ discutindo qual era o valor na posição 0 da memória... entraram até no mérito do capacitor estar ou não carregado. Não sei a resposta, não manjo de eletrônica. :P

Comment: @OnoSendai muito longe de ser perfeita. Até eu sei que dá para melhorar muito. E não está tão bem proseada :)

Comment: @bigown perfeição, assim como beleza, está nos olhos de quem vê. =) Está sintética e indo ao ponto.

Answer (score 75):

[image: Ensō, o símbolo da iluminação, força, elegância, o universo e o vazio]

<sub>Assim disse o Mestre Programador: *Mesmo que o programa tenha apenas três linhas, algum dia alguém haverá de dar manutenção.*</sub>

---

Diz a lenda que em uma longínqua província havia um monastério onde o Mestre Programador compartilhava seus ensinamentos. Um de seus diálogos foi a respeito de NULL.

'*Mestre*', perguntou o analista júnior da corte de Wu, '*O que significa `NULL`?*'

'*Você me pergunta sobre o indecifrável*', respondeu o Mestre Programador. '`NULL` é o que nunca foi, e nunca será.'

'É seu reflexo em um lago que nunca existiu.
O filho que nunca foi concebido.
O amor que nunca chamou de seu, porque lhe faltou coragem.
É o escuro do mundo, e além.'

'É o objeto que nunca salvei?'

'Não. Este objeto foi destruído pelo *Garbage Collector*, após ser `Disposed();`.'

'É a variável que declarei, porém nunca inicializei?'

'Não. Na variável não inicializada existe o *potencial* para a grandiosidade; seu futuro não está escrito ainda, e talvez nem exista - porém seu lugar está reservado na história do mundo. Ela é `undefined`, ou `uninitialized`.'

'E porque tantas linguagens implementam `NULL`?'

'Porque precisamos admitir nossa ignorância. O que não sabemos, não pode ser descrito; o que não tem valor não pode ser avaliado.'

'Então porque não utilizar zero, ou um espaço em branco?'

'Você deseja um zero porque sua mente não consegue abandonar o conceito de *algo*. Ela associa o zero, uma ausência numérica, ao nada - e mesmo o nada é mais que `NULL`. Seu código então carregará uma semente de entropia. Ele estará separado do *Zen*, e a caminho de tornar-se *[código spaguetti](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31490/3117)*.'

'Mas, Mestre... então por quê, em PHP, `(array() == null);`?'

O Mestre Programador então suspirou. Esta seria uma tarde longa.

Comment: Eu sabia que você ia fazer isto e vai ter mais votos que a minha :D

Comment: Relacionado? [O que é código spaghetti?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31490/3117) :P

Comment: @bigown ah, mas é um assunto tão interessante! valia a versão em prosa. =)

Comment: @OnoSendai, por essa eu não esperava! Muito boa! :D

Comment: @Math obrigado pelo link, adicionei à resposta. =)

Comment: Essa é a resposta mais mítica que já li aqui no SOpt.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez É a respeito de NULL. Só poderia ser misteriosa...

Comment: Esse mestre da programação é um filósofo

Answer (score 11):

No site do [Macoratti](http://www.macoratti.net/null.htm), ele define NULL da seguinte forma:

> Null
>   Um valor que indica dados ausentes ou desconhecidos em um campo. Você pode usar valores Null em expressões. Valores Null podem ser inseridos em campos dos quais informações são desconhecidas, assim 
>   como em expressões e consultas.

Na minha concepção ele é um tipo de dados que não é vazio e não é zero, pra mim ele é uma informação não preenchida, ou melhor dizendo, não definida.

Answer (score 8):

`Null` é basicamente ausência de valor.

Ex:

```
public $variavel = 0; //não é nulo!

public $variavel; // é nulo
```

Answer (score 5):

`NULL` significa nulo, sem valor. Imagine, por exemplo, uma propriedade opcional de saldo aceitando qualquer número real. Sendo opcional não há número a ser atribuído que indique que não há saldo atribuído, pois 0, valores positivos e valores negativos são valores válidos de saldo. Atribuir `NULL` indica que não há valor atribuído. É simplesmente uma representação de *valor nenhum*.

Answer (score 4):

> **NULL**, NIHIL, N/C - tudo isso significa nulo, sem resposta, em branco.
>
> O valor especial **NULL** representa que a variável não tem valor. NULL é o único valor possível do tipo **NULL**.
>
> **Null** é o caracter ASCII "00" , é o valor de uma variável que ainda não foi inicializada

Comment: Apesar de ser apenas citações, não entendi o que essa resposta tem de errada, seria legal quem negativou dar a sua opinião.