# O que é o operador "?."?

Tags: c#, operadores

Estou vendo as funções que o C# 6.0 trouxe, e apareceu um exemplo de código assim:

C# 5.0

```
var vendor = new Company();
var location = default(string);
if (vendor != null)
  if (vendor.ContactPerson != null)
    if (vendor.ContactPerson.HomeAddress != null)
      location = vendor.ContactPerson.HomeAddress.LineOne;
Console.WriteLine(location);
```

C# 6.0

```
var vendor = new Company();
var location = vendor?.ContactPerson?.HomeAddress?.LineOne;
WriteLine(location);
```

Ambos têm a mesma funcionalidade, porém no segundo exemplo tudo é feito usando uma condicional *inline*.

Fazer um *inline if* com dois valores é fácil, mas não entendi muito bem como isso funciona.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Este é o operador *conditional access* ou *null propagation* ou *safe navigation*. Ainda não escolhi qual usar :) Mas acho que o segundo é melhor.

Como era tão frequente a verificação se um objeto é nulo antes de fazer alguma operação (como mostrado no primeiro exemplo), era um [padrão de projeto tão utilizado, seria útil que a linguagem tivesse uma facilidade para isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16204/101).

Note que o acesso a qualquer membro do objeto pode ser "protegido" com este operador. Métodos também podem ser chamados. Obviamente a chamada só ocorrerá se o objeto não for nulo.

O resultado de uma expressão `objeto ?. membro` será `null`, caso o `objeto` seja `null`. E como as expressões podem ser encadeadas, o primeiro `null` que ele encontrar todas as outras sub-expressões encontradas a seguir valerão `null` também. Ele nem vai tentar avaliar o resto, o resultado final será `null`. E isto é importante, ela é uma operação de curto-circuito, ou seja, nem tenta executar o resto quando não há mais o que fazer.

Os dois códigos apresentados na pergunta **não** são exatamente equivalentes. Neste caso até será, por coincidência, por se tratar de um caso específico raramente usado onde se quer como resultado *default* um `null`. Neste caso a inicialização da *string* `location` é um `null` em qualquer situação. Mas pense que se ela tivesse sido inicializada com `""`, ou seja, se fosse uma *string* vazia, seria diferente.

No primeiro ao final da operação se `vendor` for nulo, o conteúdo de `location` não será alterado, ou seja, ele valerá `""`. No segundo código ele valerá `null`, afinal o resultado de uma operação com um objeto `null` é `null`.

## Vamos ver mais sobre o operador

Este código provocará uma exceção **na última linha** por tentar acessar um objeto nulo:

```
string texto = null;
string parte = "";
parte = texto?.Substring(0, 1);
WriteLine($"{parte.Length}");
```

Obviamente poderíamos ter usado o operador `?.` antes do `Length` e evitar a exceção.

Se adicionar esta linha:

```
int tamanho = parte.Length;
```

Gera uma exceção porque não dá para pegar o tamanho de um objeto nulo. Certo? Então vamos fazer isto:

```
int tamanho = parte?.Length;
```

Resolve?

Nem compila. Afinal agora a expressão possivelmente resulta um nulo. Um `int` não pode ser nulo. Então teríamos que fazer isto:

```
int? tamanho = parte?.Length;
```

Um inteiro anulável pode conter todos os resultados possíveis desta expressão, inclusive o valor `null`.

Só que neste caso está usando um tipo diferente do que normalmente se usa só para resolver um problema que não existia. Aí é melhor fazer do jeito antigo:

```
int tamanho = parte != null ? parte.Length : 0;
```

ou mesclando o antigo com o novo:

```
int tamanho = parte?.Length ?? 0;
```

Note que o mesmo operador pode ter sintaxe diferente em outro contexto:

```
Cliente cliente = clientes?[0]; //isto também é o operador de propagação de nulo
```

Outro exemplo de simplificação é na verificação se um objeto possui um membro:

```
(objeto as IExemplo)?.Exemplo();
```

Se o `objeto` não implementa esta interface `IExemplo`, o resultado da operação será nulo, portanto o método `Exemplo()` não será chamado e não provocará erro.

Em tese ajudaria programadores serem mais cuidadosos com código. Tem muito código por aí que não dá erro de *null reference* por coincidência. Um dia, cai na situação que o objeto é nulo e a aplicação quebra sem o incauto se dar conta. Embora não sei se vai ajudar muito porque tem muito programador que desconhece as "novidades" do C# 3, e alguns até mesmo do C# 2. E obviamente nem conhece tudo o que já existia no C# 1. Também vai acontecer da pessoa achar que isto resolve tudo, que deve usar em todo lugar, sem pensar. O operador de acesso ao membro `.` ou `[]` ainda deve ser o operador padrão de acesso.

#### Thread-safe

O seu uso pode ser mais *thread-safe* em alguns casos por usar uma variável temporária para armazenar o resultado da expressão. Exemplo de ganho:

```
//necessário para ser thread-safe
EventHandler<decimal> precoOnChanged = OnPrecoChanged;
if (precoOnChanged != null) {
    preco = value;
    precoOnChanged (this, value);
}
```

Se transforma em:

```
preco = value;
OnPrecoChanged?.Invoke(this, value) //Invoke é usado p/ resolver ambiguidade c/ delegate
```

## Evite que o nulo aconteça

Um recurso do .NET 4 que as pessoas ignoram é o uso de contratos (ele tem sido abandonado ultimamente). Com ele é possível nem precisar disto e evitar verificações contra nulo em tempo de execução, detectando em tempo de desenvolvimento:

```
public int ProcuraTeste(string texto) { //não compila se texto for null
    Contract.Requires(texto != null); //isto pode ser eliminado do runtime
    return texto.IndexOf("teste");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/NullPropagation.cs).

Claro que isto não é solução para tudo. Há casos que só dá para saber em tempo de execução, ou seja, o nulo é algo esperado como um valor válido. [Há muita confusão sobre o que é um nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90363/101). Se ele fosse inválido, o sistema de tipos, o compilador ou análise estática deveriam detectar e impedir isto.

## Simplificando sem este operador

Como informação adicional, no C# 5 dá para simplificar um pouco o código:

```
if (vendor != null && vendor.ContactPerson != null && vendor.ContactPerson.HomeAddress != null)
    location = vendor.ContactPerson.HomeAddress.LineOne;
```

Comment: Interessante esse questão dos contratos. Só uma dúvida, quanto tempo faz que programa em C#/.NET

Comment: Resposta complicada. 14 anos? ou 0 anos?

Comment: Acho importante essa questão do termo, as vezes as linguagens tem um termo diferente para um comportamento exatamente igual, mas por causa do contexto da linguagem o termo muda. No Ruby ele é chamado de Safe Navigation, como não tem null lá (somente nil), não faz sentido o termo Null Propagation, já no C# faz muito mais sentido, fica mais explicito que o tipo de retorno vai ser um Nullable.

Answer (score 9):

Este código não é a respeito de *inline `if`s*, mas a respeito de avaliações de `NULL` em cascata.

No exemplo acima, o desenvolvedor deseja obter o valor de `vendor.ContactPerson.HomeAddress.LineOne`.

Entretanto, várias propriedades precisam ser testadas por valores `null`: `vendor`, `ContactPerson`, `HomeAddress` e - finalmente - `LineOne`.

Em C#5 ou inferior, seria necessário implementar um teste para cada objeto.

Com a nova sintaxe, você agora pode avaliar cadeia de NULL em uma única linha.

Comment: Então quer dizer que isso só serve para os casos onde eu queira avaliar se um valor é ou não é igual à `null`

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa Exatamente. E muitas implementações precisam disso - por exemplo, `HttpContext.Current.Request` para aplicações web. Pode não haver contexto corrente, ou um Request.

Comment: FWIW, Esse operador é chamado "Null conditional Operator".