# Código que arrendonda valor decimal em C# para Java/Android

Tags: java, c#, android, decimal

Tenho um código que arredonda um valor do tipo `decimal` para casas que eu quiser, e gostaria de implementá-lo no Android em Java porém estou tendo algumas dificuldades, segue abaixo o código em C#.

```
public static class Valor
{
    public static decimal Arredondar(decimal valor, int casasDecimais)
    {
        var valorNovo = decimal.Round(valor, casasDecimais);
        var valorNovoStr = valorNovo.ToString("F" + casasDecimais, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        return decimal.Parse(valorNovoStr);
    }

    public static decimal? Arredondar(decimal? valor, int casasDecimais)
    {
        if (valor == null) return null;
        return Arredondar(valor.Value, casasDecimais);
    }
}
```

Pelo que pesquisei eu teria que usar `Bigdecimal` porem estou tendo vários problemas.

Comment: Podemos ajudar se você falar quais são os problemas. Não parece ter problemas, embora não sei se precisa de tudo isto. Não sei qual é objetivo. Não parece precisar de `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei bem qual é o objetivo, mas não parece precisar do `BigDecimal` (a não ser alguma coisa do lado do Java, mas C# é C#). O `Decimal` não tem problemas de arredondamento. Na verdade me parece ser bem mais simples arredondar do que está neste código. A não ser que tenha algum objetivo que não esteja na pergunta:

```
public static decimal Arredondar(decimal valor, int casasDecimais) => decimal.Round(valor, casasDecimais);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/p4N4ve). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O7kftK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/RoundSpecific2.cs).

É tão simples que eu acho que nem precisa deste método.

Não vejo porque teria diferença no Android. Não misture o dado com a apresentação do dado.

Para o anulável, tem um jeito de usar o mesmo método, desde que use o [operador de *null propagation* do C# 6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101). Para o não anulável, não precisa usar este método, mas se quiser usar para manter a consistência, ok. Para isto usei método de extensão.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IOwMHy). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ww7lil). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/RoundSpecific.cs).

Comment: Realmente verifiquei aqui e consegui fazer sem o BigDecimal, Obrigado bigown.