# O que causa o 'System.NullReferenceException'?

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, nullpointerexception

Vez ou outra a execução de meus sistemas são interrompidos por esse erro, quando acontece, um `if(atributo != null)` costuma resolver, mas isso polui o código, "Ah, mas essa variável precisa ter um valor né?" o problema acontece justamente quando vou atribuir um valor enquanto preencho os atributos de um objeto, esse erro aparece.

> "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in NomeDoProjeto.dll but was not handled in user code"*

Tenho uma classe associativa que guarda `Permissoes` de uma página e o usuário que tem essa permissão, enquanto tento preencher a associativa (`FluxoUsuario`) ele aponta o erro:

Segue trecho de `FluxosController.cs`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vwfluxo.Usuarios.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (Request.Params["cb" + i] != null) 
                    {
                        FluxoUsuario fu = new FluxoUsuario();

                        var a = bool.Parse(Request.Form["cb" + i].Split(',')[0]);
                        var b = Request.Params["rb" + i]; //Pega valor do radioButton

                        if (a)//Verifica se a checkBox está marcada
                        {
                            if(db.FluxoUsuario.ToList().Where(x => x.Usuario.Equals(vwfluxo.Usuarios[i])).Count() > 0 == true)
                            {

                            }

                            fu.Fluxo.FluxoID = fluxo.FluxoID; //O Erro acontece nessa linha.
                     //fu.Fluxo é do tipo Fluxo, FluxoID é int. fu.Fluxo.FluxoID realmente precisa estar null quando acontece o erro, afinal, está sendo atribuido um valor para ele nesse momento.

                            fu.Usuario.IDUser = vwfluxo.Usuarios[i].IDUser;

                            fu.Fluxo = fluxo;
                            fu.Usuario = vwfluxo.Usuarios[i];

                            if (b == "ler")
                                fu.TipoPermissao = TipoPermissao.Ler;
                            else
                                fu.TipoPermissao = TipoPermissao.LerEscrever;

                            if (!fluxo.UsuariosPermitidos.Contains(fu))
                            {
                                fluxo.UsuariosPermitidos.Add(fu);
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
```

Comment: Se você está tentando definir o valor de uma propriedade de um objeto, como por exemplo `Objeto.Nome`, e o objeto for nulo esse erro ocorre. Se você postar o trecho exato onde o erro ocorre, posso ajudar mais.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Causa por tentar acessar uma variável que deveria ter um [objeto por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) e tem nada ali, ou seja, ele é nulo, portanto ela não foi inicializada com um valor válido. Isto nunca ocorre em [objetos por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101), a não ser que os modifique para serem anuláveis.

Em C# 8 é possível ligar uma proteção para nunca acontecer, desde que se programe pensando nisso sempre e não tenha legados. Infelizmente as pessoas não querem aprender as novidades da linguagem e ficam sofrendo com problemas que já deveriam ser ultrapassados.

Quando o erro ocorre significa que há um erro de programação. Então o programador deve corrigi-lo e não tentar fazer alguma coisa milagrosa no código. É muito raro querer manipular um erro deste tipo, no máximo deve *logar* e avisar o usuário que houve um erro de programação (eu sei que a pessoa vai disfarçar e dizer que não é erro de programação, ninguém quer assumir a culpa :) ).

Se o objeto não deveria ser nulo, então tem que descobrir porque está assim e arrumar isto. Se ele estar nulo é uma possibilidade a ser considerada como normal, talvez por indicar alguma falha anterior então deve tomar certos cuidados. Nos casos onde se espera ter um objeto nulo a solução mais comum realmente é verificar se ele está neste estado e não deixar o acesso ocorrer em hipótese alguma.

Em C# 6 é possível usar o [operador de *null propagation*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101) que evita o acesso ao objeto quando ele é nulo. Mas é preciso um pouco de cuidado, porque isto evita o erro, mas não fazer nada pode ser uma ação errada a tomar.

Objetos por referência costumam ser inicializados com o operador `new` (*string* tem um literal, alguns métodos retornam um novo objeto). Isto é inicializar o objeto, tentar acessar seus membros para colocar dados lá dentro dele produzirá um erro porque o objeto não existe. Ele precisa primeiro existir, depois colocar valores dentro.

O `new` chamará um [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) padrão ou ou criado pelo programador para aquele tipo.

## Caso específico

Teria que ver como o objeto do tipo `FluxoUsuario` está sendo construído. A variável `fu` não é nula, dá para ver fácil. Mas o membro `Fluxo` - que é uma variável também - faz parte dela, não foi inicializado em lugar algum do código apresentado. Ele foi inicializado pelo construtor de `FluxoUsuario` ou por padrão em sua declaração? Duvido, então ou precisa colocar isto no tipo ou então fazer isto manualmente neste código. Prefiro a primeira solução. Aí `fu.Fluxo` deixará de ser nulo e este erro não correrá mais. Claro que poderá ocorrer em outros lugares. Tem cara que também vai ocorrer em `fu.Usuario`. Não posso afirmar só com as informações apresentadas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, erro total meu mesmo, ao tentar preencher apenas o ID de fu.Fluxo, o resto dos atributos ficavam nulos, retirando as linhas onde atribuía o ID isolado e passando um objeto completo para ele foi possível resolver o problema.