# Como resolver Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Possuo um `GridView` populado com dados de um BD MySQL funcionando perfeitamente.

Possuo também um botão para o transformar em uma tabela para ser inserida em um PDF utilizando iTextSharp que também funciona perfeitamente, exceto quando realizo um filtro específico por data neste grid, mesmo que ao realizar o filtro me sejam mostrados os dados corretos.

Possuo também outro tipo de filtro que funciona perfeitamente quando tento gerar o PDF. **O erro só se dá quando estipulo um intervalo de datas**, sejam quais forem. A mensagem `Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object` é exibida e por mais que já tenha procurado, não encontrei solução para meu caso.

Deixo aqui a parte do código que aponta o erro. A linha `tabela.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[n, j].Value.ToString()));` é a indicada pelo Visual Studio como o problema.

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; n++)
    {
        tabela.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[n, j].Value.ToString()));
        tabela.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        tabela.WidthPercentage = 100;
    }
}
```

Reforço: **somente** quando realizo o filtro entre datas é apresentado o erro!

O código em questão se encontra no botão de gerar o PDF.

Comment: Vulgo `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essa exceção ocorre quando você chama um método (ou, mais genericamente, faz referência) a um objeto `null`. No caso da linha onde o erro ocorre, um dos objetos (`tabela`, `dataGridView1`, `dataGridView1[n, j]` ou `dataGridView1[n, j].Value`) é `null`.  Convém descobrir qual deles é.

É quase certo que `tabela` não é, senão nunca funcionaria, quer haja filtro de data, quer não.

`dataGridView`, igualmente, teria causado problema no primeiro `for` se fosse nulo (já que se refere à coleção `dataGridView1.Rows` nele.

Como `n` e `j` são restritos aos limites em `dataGridView1.Rows.Count` e `dataGridView1.Columns.Count`, respectivamente, não é provável que tenhamos estourado os limites das respectivas coleções. Então nos resta que o problema deve estar em `dataGridView1[n, r].Value`, isto é, para algum valor de `n` e `r` o resultado de `Value` deve ser `null`.

Existem dois modos de se resolver este problema. O primeiro é usando o operador de coalescência `??`, assim:

```
tabela.AddCell(new Phrase((dataGridView1[n, j].Value ?? "").ToString()));
```

Alternativamente, e de certa forma mais seguramente, se pode (deve) substituir as referências ao método `φ.ToString()` por chamadas ao método `Convert.ToString(φ)`, que não dá pau quando `φ` é nulo:

```
tabela.AddCell(new Phrase(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[n, j].Value)));
```

Comment: Mesmo se estourasse os limites da condição não teria nenhum NullReferenceException. De qqr forma sua suposição final é muito provavelmente onde está o problema.

Comment: @jbueno Tem razão, provavelmente nesse caso seria `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Muito obrigado jbueno. Resolveu meu problema. Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Considerando o sucesso desta pergunta que foi respondida de forma específica e pode ajudar muito outras pessoas, vou responder genericamente.

## Exceção

A mensagem apresentada ocorre quando uma exceção `NullReferenceException` é lançada, e é dela que devemos falar.

O primeiro ponto que devemos tocar é que este é um erro de programação e você não deve capturar a exceção e tentar tratar no código, como boa parte das exceções. Sendo um erro de programação você deve corrigí-lo.

Note que em versões mais novas do C# e .NET você pode fazer códigos que essa exceção se torne quase impossível de ser lançada. Desde C# 8 é possível trabalhar com objetos por referência que não podem ser nulos, e este tipo de erro pode ser detetado no momento da compilação. Então se você está tendo esse erro no momento que eu escrevo esta resposta ou depois, está programando de forma antiga, não robusta e deveria começar modernizar seu código.

Se é uma situação que não pode evitar o erro ou está usando uma versão antiga da tecnologia (pra que?), então tem que entender o que acontece.

Leia [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14492/101. Apenas em tipos por referência que isto acontece.

Estes tipos possuem uma referência para um objeto que está em outro lugar. Então cria-se uma instância do objeto, armazena-a no *heap* e guarda uma referência (ponteiro) para o objeto na variável.

Mas e se você esquecer de criar essa instância e guardar a referência na variável, qual o valor da variável? Será um valor 0 para a referência, ou seja, será um valor nulo, será um valor que não consegue chegar a objeto algum. Isso não pode acontecer, e por isso as [versões mais novas do C# não permite isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/397664/101) (se você usar a opção correta). [Ver também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106133/101). Nas versões antigas ou se não tiver a compilação verificando isso, então você tem que inspecionar o código manualmente para garantir que o objeto seja criado e colocado na variável.

Se a referência é nula e não tem um objeto para operar não pode acessar nenhuma parte do objeto, não pode chamar métodos em cima dele.

## *Debug*

A exceção é lançada e aprece essa mensagem quando falhou em fazer isso. Tem que pegar o ponto onde deu o erro e ir analisando o código de trás para frente até chegar no ponto onde a variável que está usando foi declarada e ver em que ponto deveria criar o objeto, possivelmente no momento que declara já deveria criar o objeto.

Em alguns raros casos é possível que em algum lugar acabou guardando um nulo de propósito na variável, mas isso é um erro e deveria evitar fazer isso.

A outra resposta teve que chutar onde estava o erro porque não foi colocado código necessário para achar onde está o erro, ou seja, onde a  variável foi declarada e não inicializada.

É muito comum que códigos assim deem erros em algumas situações mas não em outras. Especialmente em orientação a objeto onde uma variável pode ou não estar inicializada. Mas esta não é uma forma robusta de fazer código. Ou deveria inicializar sempre, ou deveria ter um controle mais apurado de quando deve inicializar ou deveria verificar antes de usar o objeto se ele é nulo.

## Correção

Verificar se o objeto deveria ser nulo é algo que deve ser evitado e só em alguns casos faz sentido usar esta técnica, ou seja, precisa que o valor nulo tenha algum significado na regra de negócio do objeto. Em C# 8 com o mecanismo de referências anuláveis ligado naquele contexto é que pode fazer isso. Ou seja, só se o nulo for um valor pertinente, e se ele é útil tem que verificar sempre antes de usar. No momento C# não tem um mecanismo melhor, mas dizem que terá.

Ao contrário do que is a resposta aceita, usar [`??`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101), ou mesmo [`?.`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101), não deveria ser a solução, salvo se o nulo faz parte da informação útil, o que não parece ser o caso, ele aconteceu sem querer.

O filtro deve fazer com que o objeto não tenha sido criado.

Mudar para `Convert.ToString()` não dá o erro, mas pode não ser a solução porque ele não gerará um texto com algo útil. Pode ser que seja suficiente para o que deseja. Mas é tratar o sintoma, o certo *talvez* fosse ter um objeto inicializado mesmo com filtro. Depende do que deseja.

Corrija a causa do problema sempre que for pertinente.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

[O SOen tem uma resposta excelente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/221800) com exemplos de situações que gera o problema.