# Existe desvantagem ou é prejudicial utilizar tipos nulos?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, tipagem, nullable

Sempre tenho problemas em receber valores nulos do banco de dados pois esqueço de utilizar os tipos anuláveis e me deparo com o mesmo problema:

> O tipo não pode ser nulo

Isso geralmente acontece com atributos `int`, mas agora aconteceu com o `double` e a minha pergunta é a seguinte:

Existe desvantagem ou é prejudicial utilizar tipos *nullable*? ([documentação aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, sempre que o nulo não fizer parte do seu domínio, o que é raro ocorrer.

Tanto é ruim que em C# 8 os [tipos por referência que eram nulos por padrão deixam de existir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (se você ligar isso, não tem como ser obrigatório porque quebraria muito código, mas recomendo ligar sempre que possível, mesmo que dê algum trabalho de atualização de código). Então se ligar isso só poderá usar um nulo explicitamente, por exemplo `string?`.

Se eles estão arrumando um jeito de minimizar o seu uso, porque você vai incentivar o uso onde já é opcional? Sim, tem casos para usar, por isso que existe a possibilidade de declarar um tipo como `int?`, por exemplo.

Em geral mesmo em banco de dados não deveria usar nulo, mas há casos pra usar. Em tempos de ORM deveria usar menos ainda (embora isso possa dificultar a modelagem). Boas modelagens reduzem muito o uso de nulos (usar o nulo costuma ser o caminho fácil... e errado). Quando você tem um nulo é um sinal de alerta pra ver se não está fazendo algo errado. Mas se no banco de dados estiver aceitando nulo então não é opção você declarar como não nulo em C#, tem que existir uma simetria (se estiver fazendo na mão tem alguma forma de minimizar isso, mas não sei se compensa o trabalho e se não fizer certo pode ser problemático).

Não tem nada de subjetivo nisso, é objetivo que deve evitar o nulo ao máximo, o que é subjetivo é onde fazer, o julgamento vai depender do contexto, a tecla que vivo batendo, e essa é a diferença de seguir boas práticas. Se procurar aqui já respondi sobre isso algumas vezes e tenho palestras sobre o assunto.

No caso dos tipos por valor tem algumas outras desvantagens. Uma delas é que ele ocupa mais espaço para ter o controle do nulo. Em um `double` que ocupa 8 bytes vai passar ocupar 16 bytes (em alguns casos pode ser só 9 bytes), mesmo precisando apenas 1 bit para controlar o nulo. É mais lento, não atômico e tem uma série de construções que não lida bem com tipos nulos (funciona, mas acontece coisas esquisitas ou tem que fazer algum artifício para funcionar, em alguns casos tem que acessar a propriedade `Value` para pegar o valor), e quando algo espera um `int` e vai um `int?` pode dar resultados inesperados em alguns casos. Mais motivos para evitar esse tipo de coisa.

C# é fortemente tipada, até certo ponto, não é 100% e raro as que são, e são linguagens bem chatas :). O que a  uma resposta aqui quer dizer é que ela é estaticamente tipada e, ao contrário do que a resposta diz, os tipos anuláveis facilitam o código quebrar em tempo de execução e isso por si só já é bem prejudicial. E a comparação com C++ está completamente equivocada porque inteiros em C++ não podem ser nulos. E se estiver falando de um tipo que pode ser nulo em C#, antes de C# 8 ou depois se não ligar a nova *feature*, pode do mesmo jeito que C++. E se uma variável inteira anulável for usada em uma soma você pode garantir o resultado fazendo um condicional antes. Em alguns casos pode usar um operador como o [*null propagation*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101), se quer que um nulo gere outro nulo como resultado.

## Conclusão

Aceitar nulos deixa o código menos robusto, menos performático porque para dar a robustez tem que verificar se o objeto não é nulo antes de usar e por ocupar mais espaço (se o tipo não for por referência). Esquecendo de fazer isto corre o risco da quebra. Então evite o seu uso, algumas linguagens nem permitem o uso de nulo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maniero, pergunta mas em casos como esse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239486/7981707 que a pessoa precisa tornar nullable?

Comment: O que que tem? Não sei se entendi. É algo que não está na resposta?

Comment: Reli varias vezes e encontrei a resposta para minha pergunta comentada ;)

Answer (score 4):

Isso é um pouco subjetivo, pois diz respeito a práticas de programação, mas os valores nulos tem sido responsáveis por muitos dos erros de lógica desde sua concepção.

Uma matéria interessante para ver sobre isso é [Null References: O Erro de um Bilhão de Dólares](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/), em que Tony Hoare, o próprio inventor do `null`, explica melhor porque null existe (spoiler: foi preguiça de criar uma solução melhor) e porque ele é terrível.

E se não puder ler inglês, alguns sites que você pode encontrar no Google comentam sobre essa matéria.

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta do nosso amigo:

Se você trabalha com banco de dados, é de recomendação utilizar variáveis `nullables` de acordo com o tipo da coluna. Caso contrário vai sempre ocupar espaço com dados desnecessários no banco onde receberia `null`.

Agora quanto a utilização das variáveis na linguagem sim, você pode ter alguns problemas com `NullPointerReferences`, inclusive como nosso amigo na outra resposta já explicou bem em sua resposta.

Answer (score 3):

C# é uma linguagem fortemente *tipada* e isso garante uma consistência do código evitando muitos erros em tempo de execução. Os tipos nullables são extremamente importantes para essa consistência.

Por exemplo, você está fazendo uma operação de soma:

```
int i = a + b;
```

Se *a* ou *b* pode ser nulo, como você garante o resultado da informação? Nesse cenário o código nem compilaria. No C++ este código é compilado, porém o resultado pode ser totalmente inesperado.

É extremamente importante e útil que você faça sua tipagem pensando no resultado que você espera e à partir daí defina se irá usar nullable ou não.

Answer (score -2):

Eu costumava usar nulos em C# e confesso que não é boa ideia. Quase sempre o código não funcionava da maneira correta. Sugiro usar algo do tipo: `!string` ou então: `nullables` ou então `NullPointerReferences`.