# Que tipo de dado usar para armazenar data de falecimento num cadastro (DateTime ou string)?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, tipagem, modelagem

Tenho um cadastro de pessoas onde preciso armazenar as datas de nascimento (`DateBirth`) e falecimento (`DateDeath`). Sabendo que o tipo `DateTime` em C# não pode ser vazio e seu valor inicial padrão é 01/01/0001 00:00:00, o que não faz sentido para o preenchimento de um campo que trata de uma data de falecimento de uma pessoa, que solução vocês aplicariam?

Definiriam mesmo assim a propriedade como do tipo `DateTime` e fariam algum tipo de tratamento depois? Definiriam como do tipo `string`? Ou que outra solução sugeririam?

Abaixo, trecho do código da classe da entidade em C#.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateBirth { get; set; }

    // Definir a propriedade como DateTime há um valor inicial pré-definido: 01/01/0001
    // public DateTime DateDeath { get; set; }
    
    // Ou definir a propriedade como string, iniciando-a com valor vazio,
    // mas sem os recursos de validação do tipo DateTime.
    // public string DateDeath { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DateTime?` ([tipo anulável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125827/101)) que permite um valor nulo e assim pode indicar que essa data ainda não existe. Obviamente precisa tratar de forma adequada para não gerar erros, mas desde C# 8 isso ficou mais fácil, recomendo usar pelo menos esta versão e adotar as práticas dela. Não use `string`, isso não faz o menor sentido.

Aliás, se estiver programando certo e de forma moderna todos os tipos não são anuláveis e só usando a interrogação é que eles se tornam anuláveis. Ver mais em [Existe desvantagem ou é prejudicial utilizar tipos nulos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/397664/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Maniero. Vou seguir a sua dica! 