# O que é o operador "!."?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, nullable

No C# 8.0 foi introduzido o operador `!` (*null-null*).

Exemplo:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    Person? p = Find("John");
    if (IsValid(p))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found {p!.Name}");
    }
}
```

Qual a sua funcionalidade?

Comment: Serve para você informar ao compilador que tem certeza que de `p` não é nulo naquele momento. Isso vai impedi-lo de lançar um aviso de possível "Null Reference Exception".

Comment: BTW, se eu bem lembro, o nome utilizado pelo time do C# é null-forgiving operator.

Comment: @JéfBueno na verdade é o oposto, ele permite dar esse erro, o que não é o ideal, tem mais detalhes na resposta.

Comment: @Maniero O que eu quis dizer é que o compilador não vai te avisar do possível problema, mas o erro vai acontecer caso `p` seja nulo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `!`, neste contexto, é chamado de *null-forgiving*, também de *null-suppression*, ou *dammit* para os íntimos.

O ponto é outro operador e faz o que sempre fez.

C# 8 introduziu o que é chamado de *nullable references*. Se você conhece bem a linguagem deve imaginar que isso sempre existiu, os tipos por referência sempre foram anuláveis, diferente dos tipos por valor que inicialmente não eram anuláveis e só na versão 2 da linguagem passaram ter essa capacidade opcional usando um truque, e assim esses tipos passaram ser declarados com um `?` depois do nome (ex.: `int?`). C# 8 passou tornar linear e os tipos por referência anuláveis passaram ser declarados assim também (ex.: `string?`). Mas por questão de compatibilidade o tipo ainda funciona de forma anulável sem o `?` de forma contextual, você pode ligar ou desligar isso. Pode ver mais em [Existe desvantagem ou é prejudicial utilizar tipos nulos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/397664/101).

Então se naquele contexto de compilação estiver ligado o compilador trata os tipos por referência sem o `?` como tipos não anuláveis e o código fica mais seguro do ponto de vista de tipagem já que o nulo é uma distorção da tipagem.

Obviamente que existe uma conversa entre os tipos anuláveis e os tipos não anuláveis e os tipos não anuláveis não podem receber um valor de tipo anulável até que prove que ele não é nulo já que este não é um valor aceitável. Em alguns casos o compilador pode provar isso, em outros o programador precisa dizer isso para o compilador.

è aí que entra esse operador, ele diz que aquele objeto não tem um valor nulo, então o compilador deve calar a boca e aceitar que ele pode ser usado com um tipo não anulável. Sem ele o compilador daria erro para dar mais segurança ao código.

Aí, o que acontece se o objeto der um nulo? Dá erro de execução e quebra a aplicação se não tiver uma captura de exceção) (que é um erro e programação). Você tem que ter certeza que o valor não é nulo, caso contrário tornou seu código menos seguro.

No seu exemplo eu imagino que o método `IsValid()` determina que o valor não é nulo (de fato na documentação com código idêntico é assim), então você estaria seguro. O compilador não poderia garantir isso.

Porém esse operador não precisa ser usado em outra situação:

```
Person? p = Find("John");
if (p != null && p.Name != null) WriteLine($"Found {p.Name}");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/NonNullGaranteed.cs).

Assim o compilador sabe que não é nulo e aceita. Pode ser escrito assim também: `p is not null` ([*pattern matching*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410484/101)).

Você também marcar certos métodos ([`\[NotNullWhen(true)\]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullwhenattribute?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)) como garantidores que o objeto não é nulo, quando isso estiver disponível poderia dizer que o `IsValid()` é um caso desses e aí o compilador pode garantir a não nulidade mesmo no código original, e de fato é mostrado assim também na documentação. [Veja mais](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Então seu uso deve ser bem pouco em códigos modernos. O .NET mudou todos seus métodos para deixar o mais seguro possível, mas não pode fazer milagres para não quebrar a compatibilidade, uma pena, pagaremos um preço para sempre por um erro no início. Esse é talvez o maior erro do C#.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: "ou dammit para os íntimos" :D :D :D