# System.NullReferenceException. Como incluir os campos de outra tabela?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Amigos, eu tinha uma tabela `Pessoa` que continha muitas informações sobre o usuário. Decidi criar uma tabela `Aluno` para separar as informações. Minhas tabelas são assim:

> Pessoa: `Cod`, `Nome`, `Email`, `Senha` 
> Aluno: `Cod`, `Status`, `Data_Registro`, `PessoaId`

Estou tentando obter uma lista de pedidos do usuário conectado. No entanto, minha tabela `Pedidos` tem uma chave para a tabela `Alunos`, **não para a tabela** `Pessoa`. A informação do `Aluno` é nula. Como posso incluí-lo na tabela `Pessoa`?

Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 
  'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

LojaVirtual.Models.pessoa.aluno.get retornou null.
```

PedidoController.cs

```
public IActionResult Index(int pagina)
{
    pessoa pessoa = _loginPerson.GetPessoa();
    var requests= _requestRepository.ObterTodosPedidoPessoa(pagina, pessoa.aluno.Cod);

    return View(pedidos);
}
```

Médoto GetPessoa()

```
public pessoaGetPessoa()
{
    //Deserializar
    if( _sessao.Existe(Key)) {
        string pessoaJSONString = _sessao.Consultar(Key) ;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<pessoa>(pessoaJSONString);

    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Método Consultar

```
public string Consultar(string Key)
{
    return _context.HttpContext.Session.GetString(Key);
}
```

Eu agradeço por qualquer comentário!

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que causa o 'System.NullReferenceException'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106133/o-que-causa-o-system-nullreferenceexception)

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Fiz a tradução @BrunoWarmling. Vi o link que passou, mas não era bem isso!

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente, **o problema está no fato de ter uma `Pessoa` mas não ter um `Aluno`, já que a chave de `Pedidos` está ligada ao `Aluno`**. As únicas formas que vejo de fazer essa ligação seria acessando a propriedade `Cod` que está presente nas duas entidades, caso tenham o mesmo valor para os registros nas tabelas `Aluno` e `Pessoa`:

```
var requests = _requestRepository.ObterTodosPedidoPessoa(pagina, pessoa.Cod);
```

Caso o registro `Cod` não seja o mesmo para `Aluno` e `Pessoa`, vejo como solução a "ligação direta" entre `Pessoa` e `Pedido`, dado que, se entendi corretamente, sempre existe uma `Pessoa` mas nem sempre essa `Pessoa` é um `Aluno`.

Comment: Obrigado pela retorno. O Aluno sempre é uma pessoa. Quando cadastro uma pessoa na tabela "Pessoa", a tabela "Aluno" também é preenchida com um fk para "Pessoa". Eu não posso por uma chave de "Pedidos" para "Pessoa", pois outro sistema também faz consultas no banco. A solução seria realmente inserir as informações do aluno. Mas não entendo como posso fazer isso!

Comment: @EdrianBiagi como não sei qual biblioteca está usando para fazer o resgate e inserção de dados, não tenho como complementar a resposta com código atualmente, mas acredito que apenas criando um método que receba o ID de uma pessoa e as informações de `Aluno` para inserir no repositório ou fazendo o insert manualmente, já que a propriedade `Cod` também não é a mesma para `Aluno` e `Pessoa`.

Verifique também se não existe algum problema na forma como está resgatando a entidade `Aluno` já que existe um insert prévio na tabela como descreveu.