# Para que serve a "interrogação" na declaração de tipos no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem

Eu vi esse código escrito em  C#  na internet:

```
namespace Test
{
    [MicroEntitySetup(TableName = "Users")]
    public class User : MicroEntity<User>
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Como estou aprendendo C# agora, fiquei sem entender o porquê do `DateTime?`.

Qual seria a diferença entre:

```
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set}
```

E

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set }
```

O que significa essa interrogação que vem depois do tipo?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Especificamente neste caso (onde o sinal vem depois de algum tipo), significa que o tipo primitivo pode receber `null` como valor.

É um syntax sugar pra `Nullable<Tipo>`

Ex.:

```
DateTime? data = null; // Vai funcionar
DateTime data = null;  // Erro -> DateTime não pode receber null
```

---

#### Detalhe:

O `Nullable<Tipo>`, tem duas propriedades (que eu julgo) importantes.

O `HasValue` e o `Value`. O `HasValue` é um `boolean` que determina se a variável tem um valor (`true`) ou se ela é nula (`false`). O `Value` carrega o valor da variável (se ela não for nula, obviamente).

Veja o exemplo:

```
int? nullable1 = null;
int? nullable2 = 10;
    
if(nullable1.HasValue) // HasValue = false
    WriteLine(nullable1);
    
if(nullable2.HasValue) // HasValue = true
{
    WriteLine(nullable2);       // Imprime 10
    WriteLine(nullable2.Value); // Imprime 10
}
```

[Veja este mesmo exemplo no dotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jvvtGw)

Comment: Não sabia da existência Nullable<tipo> obrigado.

Answer (score 12):

Neste caso específico é um açúcar sintático para indicar um [tipo anulável](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Isto quer dizer que seu `DateTime` que normalmente não aceitaria um valor nulo, poderá aceitar.

Isto é especialmente útil para uso com campos de banco de dados que costumam aceitar nulos. Mas pode ser usado para qualquer coisa.

Note que no tipo por valor normalmente o *default* dele é algo que representa um zero (seja lá que valor seja adequado para representar isto), em geral representado pela constante `MinValue`. Quando o tipo passar ser anulável, o *default* dele é o mesmo dos tipos por referência, então passa ser um `null`.

Só é interessante ter este recurso na linguagem para os [tipos por valor. Os tipos por referência aceitam nulos por padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

O tipo anulável é uma estrutura simples com basicamente dois membros. Um é o valor e obviamente é do tipo principal e o outro é um indicador booliano se é nulo ou não. Obviamente se ele for nulo, o valor não estará disponível. Isto é necessário porque nenhum valor de um tipo por valor é inválido, é preciso de um indicado auxiliar. Obviamente há um pequeno *overhead* de memória.

A semântica permanece a do tipo por valor, mas algumas pequenas discrepâncias podem ser observadas em algumas situações bem específicas.

Todo tipo por valor pode ser implicitamente convertido para o seu equivalente anulável (note que os tipos são diferentes). O oposto não é verdadeiro

Se tiver interesse em entender seu funcionamento, tem o [fonte da classe `Nullable`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e).

No seu exemplo é sem o açúcar sintático ficaria assim:

```
public Nullable<DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pcFMI1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qdk6xD). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/NullableSyntax.cs).

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime? dtn = null;
    WriteLine(dt);
    WriteLine(dtn);
    dtn = dt;
    WriteLine(dtn);
    dt = dtn ?? default(DateTime); //daria erro de compilação se não fizesse esta verificação
    WriteLine(dtn);
    dt = dtn.GetValueOrDefault(); //também pode usar isto que faz a verificação internamente
    WriteLine(dtn);
    if (dtn != null) {
        WriteLine("tem valor");
    }
    if (dtn.HasValue) { //dá o mesmo resultado e seu uso é dispensável
        WriteLine("tem valor");
    }
```

Note que o uso direto das propriedades `HasValue` e `Value` não é necessário e normalmente não recomendado. Estas propriedades estão disponíveis para o compilador e outras ferramentas manipularem o tipo de forma adequada. Seu uso em código "normal" deve ser raro e deve ter uma justificativa. A ideia é que o tipo seja usado como se o nulo fosse nativo dele. Usá-las faria o uso do tipo anulável menos transparente e diminuiria a capacidade de açúcar sintático do recurso.

Relacionado: [Qual o significado do operador "??"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101) e [O que é o operador "?."?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101)

Comment: Bem, então vou começando a me acostumar com essas ideias de tipagem... C# é um mundo bem distante do PHP :)

Comment: Você vai entender o `Nullable` melhor depois de entender o uso de *generics*.

Answer (score 6):

A interrogação é um *açucar sintático* para declarar que um tipo primitivo pode ter o valor nulo (i.e., `Nullable<T>`) - `null` não é um valor válido para um tipo primitivo. Usando o `Nullable`, você tem um tipo que pode ter um valor primitivo **ou** nulo. A declaração

```
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

é equivalente à declaração

```
public Nullable<DateTime> BirthDate { get; set; }
```