# Aceitando campos nulos de uma Texbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, conversão-de-tipo, null

Quando eu clico em "Salvar", o programa faz uma verificação das `Texbox` com uma tratativa que eu fiz para não deixar passar números repetidos, o problema é que ele da erro se alguma `Textbox` estiver em branco. Segue abaixo o Código que fiz salvando as informações em uma planilha de Excel. Como nem sempre vou usar Todas as `Texbox`, como eu faço pra ele deixar passar sem acusar erro nas `Texbox` em branco e mande para o Excel um valor padrão `Null`?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCaixa1.Text) && checarString(txtCaixa1.Text))
{
    valores[0] = Convert.ToInt64(txtCaixa1.Text);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCaixa2.Text) && checarString(txtCaixa2.Text))
{
    // usar o link para verificar se existem textBox iguais
    if (!valores.Any(v => v.Equals(Convert.ToInt64(txtCaixa2.Text))))
    {
        valores[1] = Convert.ToInt64(txtCaixa2.Text);
        txtCaixa2.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        txtCaixa2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        messageBoxButtons();
        return;
    }
}
_oleCmd.CommandText = _Consulta;
_oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@MODELOS", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtModelo.Text.Trim();
_oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@QUANTIDADE", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtTotalCarton.Text.Trim();
_oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMEROCARTON", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCarton.Text);
_oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@SN1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCaixa1.Text);
_oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@SN2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCaixa2.Text);
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa tratar o erro e tomar um decisão do que executar nessa situação. Ou nem deixar o erro ocorrer, que é o mais correto. Ou seja, não use [`Convert.ToInt64()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101) porque ele foi feito para casos onde você tem certeza que a conversão funcionará. Quando isso não é certo deve usar [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101).

Então deve fazer algo assim:

```
long valor;
if (long.TryParse(txtCaixa1.Text, out valor)) {
    //aqui faz o que deseja se a conversão foi bem sucedida, provavelmente:
    valores[0] = valor;
} else {
    //faça aqui o que deseja, se o valor é inválido, quem sabe:
    valores[0] = 0;
}
```

Em C# 7 pode fazer:

```
if (long.TryParse(txtCaixa1.Text, out var valor)) {
    //aqui faz o que deseja se a conversão foi bem sucedida, provavelmente:
    valores[0] = valor;
} else {
    //faça aqui o que deseja, se o valor é inválido, quem sabe:
    valores[0] = 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/TryParseCS2.cs).

Tenho minhas dúvidas se deveria ser um número `long` porque depois usa `int` mesmo no mesmo campo, mas deixei como está.

Do ponto de vista do C#, se quiser realmente manda `null` não pode usar `long`, tem que usar [`long?` que aceita nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125827/101). Não sei como o Excel trata isso. Eu faria a conversão como mostrado e criaria uma variável do tipo `long?` que vai receber o número ou o nulo e colocaria o valor lá ou o `null`.

Normalmente não precisa usar `Equals()`, pode usar `==`.

Answer (score 0):

O erro está nas 3 ultimas linhas

```
oleCmd.CommandText = _Consulta;
    _oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@MODELOS", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtModelo.Text.Trim();
    _oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@QUANTIDADE", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txtTotalCarton.Text.Trim();
// Podem dar erro nessas 3 linhas
    _oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMEROCARTON", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCarton.Text);
    _oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@SN1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCaixa1.Text);
    _oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@SN2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCaixa2.Text);
```

Para resolver você pode implementar esta função para garantir que a string seja um numero:

```
public int TryParseNumber(string val)
    {
        var outPut = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(val, out outPut);
        return outPut;            
    }
```

E chamar eles nos parametros integer do Parameters.Add

```
 _oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@NUMEROCARTON", OleDbType.Integer).Value = TryParseNumber(txtCarton.Text);
 _oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@SN1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = TryParseNumber(txtCaixa1.Text);
 _oleCmd.Parameters.Add("@SN2", OleDbType.Integer).Value = TryParseNumber(txtCaixa2.Text);
```

Como não postou o resto do código não tem como otimizar a primeira parte dele pra saber como é utilizado o array.