# Como faço para acionar confirmar o formulário através do enter?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

Estou fazendo um programa em C# que joga o que esta dentro do `TextBox` para dentro do `Grid`, mas só estou conseguindo através de um botão. Eu quero saber como faço para o usuário fornecedor o primeiro dado, apertar enter, pular para idade, e depois que apertar enter novamente a informação ir para o `Grid`.

```
    string[] Nome = new string[5];
    int[] Idade = new int[5];
    DateTime[] Data = new DateTime[2];



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Acao();

    }



    public void Acao()
    {
        int i = 0;

        while (i < 1)
        {

            Nome[i] = textBox1.Text;
            Idade[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            dtgCliente.Rows.Add(Nome[i], Idade[i]);
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";

            i++;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente o que você deseja fazer pode ser iniciado em um evento [`Leave`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) do `TextBox`. Desta forma toda vez que sair do controle ele será disparado e atenderá o que deseja sem precisar de botão algum.

Pode ser que algum outro evento seja mais adequado dependendo do caso, na página do `Leave` tem todos que são executados durante o processo do controle. Pode ser que precise de algum controle mais específico ainda. Tem que entender o objetivo para escolher o evento certo. Não parece, mas poderia ser o [`Validating`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0).

[Consulte a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) para ver tudo o que este controle pode fazer. Tudo o que quiser saber tem na documentação, sempre procure nela.

Como nota adicional `Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);` não funciona direito. Se a pessoa não digitar um número ocorrerá uma exceção, [não é assim que faz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174943/101) e provavelmente o código deve ter outros problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo essa função para isso, aplico a todos os controles para usar o `Enter` para pular para o próximo.

Código da função:

```
 public static class Funcoes 
 { 
    /// <summary>
    /// Ao pressionar ENTER no controle, ele pula para o próximo
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_ctrl">Controle (obs: todos os controles filhos, serão afetados)</param>
    public static void TrocaTabPorEnter(Control _ctrl)
    {
        if (_ctrl.HasChildren)
        {
            foreach (Control _child in _ctrl.Controls)
            {
                if (_ctrl.HasChildren)
                    TrocaTabPorEnter(_child);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ///Não funciona para Numeric Up Down   _ctrl is Button ||
            if (_ctrl is RichTextBox || _ctrl is Button || _ctrl is TextBox || _ctrl is MaskedTextBox || _ctrl is ListBox || _ctrl is CheckBox ||  _ctrl is DateTimePicker || _ctrl is ComboBox || _ctrl is NumericUpDown || _ctrl is TrackBar || _ctrl is RadioButton || _ctrl is TabPage)
            {
                TextBox tb;
                if (_ctrl is TextBox)
                {
                    tb = ((TextBox)_ctrl);
                    if (!tb.Multiline)
                    {
                        /// inibe a ação do Enter para evitar o comportamento de
                        /// Accept em alguns casos
                        _ctrl.KeyDown += delegate(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                        {
                            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                            {
                                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                                _ctrl.FindForm().SelectNextControl(_ctrl, !e.Shift, true, true, true);
                            }
                        };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tb.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both; 
                        _ctrl.KeyDown += delegate(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                        {
                            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && e.Control)
                            {
                                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                                _ctrl.FindForm().SelectNextControl(_ctrl, !e.Shift, true, true, true);
                            }
                        };


                    }

                }
                else
                {
                        /// inibe a ação do Enter para evitar o comportamento de
                        /// Accept em alguns casos
                        _ctrl.KeyDown += delegate(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
                        {
                            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                            {
                                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                                //((Control)sender).SelectNextControl(_ctrl, !e.Shift, true, true, true);
                                _ctrl.FindForm().SelectNextControl(_ctrl, !e.Shift, true, true, true);
                            }
                        };
                }
            }
        }
    }

  }
```

Chamar a função no construtor do Form:

```
 public Form1()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        Funcoes.TrocaTabPorEnter(this);
 }
```

ps. Removi algumas particularidades do meu código da função, faça um teste por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um evento para os `textBox` para quando o usuario apertar enter e chamar a função com isso.

Utilize a variável `ActiveControl` para verificar em qual `textBox` o formulário está focado:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        acao()
    }
}

private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        acao()
    }
}

void acao(){
    if (this.ActiveControl == textBox1)
    {
        this.ActiveControl = textBox2;
    }
    else
    {
        //Colocar no Grid
    }
}
```

Na parte que está comentado, coloque o seu código para adicionar ao `Grid`. Não quis fazer isso para você porque o seu código está bem estranho quanto a isso e eu não sei a maneira que você está utilizando.

Dica: Não tem o porque utilizar array para fazer isso, no final das contas, no seu código, ele só vai utilizar o index `[0]` do array, sendo assim seria melhor você utilizar uma variável normal (única).