# Qual a utilidade da exclamação (non null assertion operator) em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, característica-linguagem, operadores, nullable

Recentemente descobri que em TypeScript podemos usar o operador de *non null assertion* simplesmente colocando um `!` onde você quer checar. Quando vi, pensei que fosse como em `C#`, que temos o `?`, que checa se o valor é nulo antes de prosseguir com a operação. Porém, ao fazer alguns testes, me parece que ele simplesmente é inútil.

Usei um *transpilador* online de TypeScript com o seguinte código:

```
var t = {
    func: function () {
        return 1;
    }
};
var g = t!.func!();
```

E ele me gera este código em JavaScript:

```
var t = {
    func: function () {
        return 1;
    }
};
var g = t.func();
```

Sendo que eu esperava que ele não desse erro caso a propriedade `func` fosse nula ou indefinida, algo como:

```
var g = t.func == null ? null : t.func();
```

Entretanto, se eu tiro o `!`, ele me gera o mesmo código. Com isso minhas dúvidas são:

- Qual a utilidade desde operador e quando devo usá-lo?
- Em quais ocasiões ele gerará um código diferente?

Comment: Acredito que essa verificação é apenas em tempo de transpilação

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que está falando em C# é o [operador `?.`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101) (desde C# 6) e não a [anotação de tipo `?`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125827/101) que já existe desde C# 2 para tipos por valor e passa existir no C# 8 para tipos por referência. C# também terá o [operador de *dammit* (`!`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e ele indicará que você, programador,  garante para o compilador que aquele valor não será nulo.

Em TypeScript funciona de forma análoga, inclusive C# se inspirou nela (ambas são do mesmo criador).

Em TS muitos códigos geram exatamente o mesmo fonte em JavaScript já que as maiores melhorias na linguagem em relação ao JS são justamente sobre ser uma linguagem tipada, portanto você pode fazer operações com mais confiança que tudo está certo. Então aquela informação serve para o compilador TS determinar se uma operação é válida ou não (o que em JS só saberia durante a execução), mas depois disso aquela informação pode desaparecer do código alvo. TS possui anotações para dar mais robustez e este operador é mais um deles, não é para mudar o código gerado, é para dar garantias.

O operador [(*non-null assertion*)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) em questão serve para você dizer ao compilador que você sabe que esta operação é segura e nunca será nula. Em alguns casos o compilador do TS poderia acha que poderia ser nulo e por causa disto não compilaria sem guardas no código (sem conseguiria se fosse fácil avaliar o fluxo do código e determinar facilmente se pode garantir a não nulidade). Essa é uma forma de você programador se responsabilizar e o compilador deixa passar, mesmo que ele tenha quase certeza que isto esteja errado. O seu uso só faz sentido em variáveis de tipos anuláveis (com anotação `?` no final), o que não é seu caso, então parece que não faz nada, mas também não gera erro.

Quais as chances de alguém altamente capacitado ter colocado algo inútil na linguagem e quais as chances da pessoa que está usando não entender seu funcionamento?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Que não era inútil eu tinha certeza po, ele só não faz o que eu pensava que fazia :v

Comment: Excelente a explicação, mas totalmente desnecessário o seu último comentário.