# Propriedade Nullable no C#

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade

Estava vendo alguns tutorias e de repente vi esta propriedade `public Nullable<int> Id {get; set;}`. O que ele significa e quando eu iria utilizá-lo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[O que estava chamando de atributo (a pergunta foi editada) na verdade é uma propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). O `public` em isolado é um atributo que determina a visibilidade da propriedade. O `Nullable<int>` sozinho é um atributo que indica o tipo desta propriedade.

Ele indica que você tem um tipo inteiro que aceita valor nulo. É necessário encapsular o tipo por valor porque não tem um dos valores do inteiro que poderia ser considerado inválido, então um campo extra é usado para marcar quando ele é nulo. Embora funcione, na verdade ninguém que sabe programar faz uso disso, é muito mais fácil e limpo usar `int?` que é a mesma coisa, ele acaba se transformando no `Nullable<int>`.

Inclusive é melhor usar a forma compacta provida pela linguagem porque em C# 8 haverá tipos anuláveis por referência, e como estes tipos possuem um valor natural inválido eles não precisam do `Nullable<T>` e aí usar a forma por extenso no tipo por valor fica assimétrico com o tipo por referência.

Pode ver mais em [Para que serve a "interrogação" na declaração de tipos no C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125827/101).

Se quiser pode ver o [fonte desta `struct`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Nullable.cs,ffebe438fd9cbf0e).]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente o `public Nullable<int> Id {get; set;}` é uma propriedade do tipo `int` que pode receber o valor null, você também pode representar dessa forma `public int? Id { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 1):

o Int normal não aceita o valor null, pois gera erro de compilação. Porém digitado dessa forma (NullAble x) ele passa a aceitar.