# Dúvida com join entre duas classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Tenho as Classes:

```
    class Procedimento
    {
        public string CodProcedimento { get; set; }
        public string NomeProcedimento { get; set; }
        public string TpSexo { get; set; }
        public int IdadeMinima { get; set; }
        public int IdadeMaxima { get; set; }
        public string CodCbo { get; set; }
    }

    class RlProcedimentoRegistro
    {
        public string CodProcedimento { get; set; }
        public string Registro { get; set; }
    }

    class ProcedimentoCompleto
    {
        public string CodProcedimento { get; set; }
        public string NomeProcedimento { get; set; }
        public string TpSexo { get; set; }
        public int IdadeMinima { get; set; }
        public int IdadeMaxima { get; set; }
        public string CodCbo { get; set; }
        public string Registro { get; set; }
    }
```

Faço um join entre as duas primeiras Classes para gerar a terceira (incluindo a propriedade Registro a ela) e incluo em uma lista:

```
listaProcedimentoCompleto = (from procedimento in listaProcedimento
                                 join rlProcedimento in listaRlProcedimentoCbo on procedimento.CodProcedimento equals rlProcedimento.CodProcedimento
                                 join rlProcedimentoRegistro in listaRlProcedimentoRegistro on procedimento.CodProcedimento equals rlProcedimentoRegistro.CodProcedimento
                                 where rlProcedimentoRegistro.Registro.Equals("01")
                                 orderby procedimento.NomeProcedimento
                                 select new ProcedimentoCompleto()
                                 {
                                     CodProcedimento = procedimento.CodProcedimento,
                                     IdadeMaxima = Convert.ToInt32(procedimento.IdadeMaxima / 12),
                                     IdadeMinima = Convert.ToInt32(procedimento.IdadeMinima / 12),
                                     NomeProcedimento = procedimento.NomeProcedimento,
                                     TpSexo = procedimento.TpSexo,
                                     CodCbo = rlProcedimento.CodCbo,
                                     Registro = rlProcedimentoRegistro.Registro
                                 }).ToList();
```

A ideia é que: A Classe Procedimento tem os códigos de uma tabela e a Classe RlProcedimentoRegistro verifica se o registro for igual a 01, e cria a nova Classe ProcedimentoCompleto.

Funciona tudo bem até aqui. O que quero é o seguinte:

A Classe RlProcedimentoRegistro NÃO CONTÉM todos os CodProcedimentos que existem na Classe Procedimento, pois existem procedimentos que não tem Registro, então não tem como fazer a ligação.

Como podem ver no código acima, eu consigo pegar todos os Procedimento que tem o Registo "01" (ou outro que eu queira), porem eu também quero pegar todos que tem Registro "01" + os que não contém registro algum, ou seja, os que não existem na tabela RlProcedimentoRegistro.

Digamos que eu tenha o seguinte

```
Procedimento.CodProcedimento = 1;
Procedimento.CodProcedimento = 2;
Procedimento.CodProcedimento = 3;
Procedimento.CodProcedimento = 4;

RlProcedimentoRegistro.CodProcedimento = 1, Registro = 01
RlProcedimentoRegistro.CodProcedimento = 3, Registro = 02
RlProcedimentoRegistro.CodProcedimento = 4, Registro = 01
```

Preciso que me retorne os Procedimentos 1 e 4 (que tem Registo "01") + Procedimento 2 (que não consta na tabela RlProcedimentoRegistro).

Tentei detalhar o máximo possível, espero que dê pra entender bem.

Comment: Você só esqueceu de dizer qual é o tipo de cada lista =D

Comment: listraProcedimento é do tipo Procedimento. listaRlProcedimentoRegistro é do tipo RlProcedimentoRegistro e listaProcedimentoCompleto é do tipo ProcedimentoCompleto

Comment: E essa `listaRlProcedimentoCbo` não serve pra nada (no contexto do exemplo)?

Comment: não. não percebi que ela estava aí, mas ela filtra a Classe Procedimento também pela propriedade CodCbo. funciona normalmente também

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faltou usar o `DefaultIfEmpty` no join. Isso faz um left join entre as listas.
Veja como fica a sua *query*

Obs.: Eu tirei algumas propriedades e aquele join que não fazia parte do escopo da pergunta porque tava confuso demais, aliás, fica como dica, tente dar uns nomes melhores pra suas classes e também organizar um pouco melhor as suas ideias no código.

```
var lista = 

    (from procedimento in listaProcedimento

    join rlProcedimentoRegistro in listaRlProcedimentoRegistro 
        on procedimento.CodProcedimento equals rlProcedimentoRegistro.CodProcedimento
        into rlProcedimentoRegistro

    from procRegistro in rlProcedimentoRegistro.DefaultIfEmpty()

    where (procRegistro == null || procRegistro.Registro == "01")
    orderby procedimento.NomeProcedimento

    select new ProcedimentoCompleto
    {
        CodProcedimento = procedimento.CodProcedimento,
        TpSexo = procedimento.TpSexo,
        Registro = procRegistro?.Registro ?? "Nulo"
    }).ToList();
```

---

Aqui vai um exemplo completão, pronto pra ser executado. Você pode [vê-lo funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aqzEGa)

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var listaProcedimento = new [] 
        {
            new Procedimento { CodProcedimento = "Proc 01",},
            new Procedimento { CodProcedimento = "Proc 02" },
            new Procedimento { CodProcedimento = "Proc 03" },
            new Procedimento { CodProcedimento = "Proc 04" },
        };

        var listaRlProcedimentoRegistro = new [] 
        {
            new RlProcedimentoRegistro { CodProcedimento = "Proc 01", Registro = "01" },
            new RlProcedimentoRegistro { CodProcedimento = "Proc 02", Registro = "02" },
        };

        var lista = 

        (from procedimento in listaProcedimento

        join rlProcedimentoRegistro in listaRlProcedimentoRegistro 
            on procedimento.CodProcedimento equals rlProcedimentoRegistro.CodProcedimento
            into rlProcedimentoRegistro

        from procRegistro in rlProcedimentoRegistro.DefaultIfEmpty()

        where (procRegistro == null || procRegistro.Registro == "01")
        orderby procedimento.NomeProcedimento

        select new ProcedimentoCompleto
        {
            CodProcedimento = procedimento.CodProcedimento,
            TpSexo = procedimento.TpSexo,
            Registro = procRegistro?.Registro ?? "Nulo"
        }).ToList();

        foreach(var r in lista)
        {
            WriteLine($"{r.CodProcedimento} - {r.Registro}");
        }
    }
}

public class Procedimento
{
    public string CodProcedimento { get; set; }
    public string NomeProcedimento { get; set; }
    public string TpSexo { get; set; }
    public int IdadeMinima { get; set; }
    public int IdadeMaxima { get; set; }
    public string CodCbo { get; set; }
}

public class RlProcedimentoRegistro
{
    public string CodProcedimento { get; set; }
    public string Registro { get; set; }
}

public class ProcedimentoCompleto
{
    public string CodProcedimento { get; set; }
    public string NomeProcedimento { get; set; }
    public string TpSexo { get; set; }
    public int IdadeMinima { get; set; }
    public int IdadeMaxima { get; set; }
    public string CodCbo { get; set; }
    public string Registro { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: obrigado, vou adaptar aqui. qual site você me recomenda pra estudar esse tipo de query pro LINQ?

Comment: Acho que não entendi. Você quer uma dica de onde estudar esse tipo de coisa?

Comment: isso mesmo, quero estudar como fazer minhas querys. sei fazer usando sql, mas esse jeito é um pouco diferente e me atrapalhei um pouco pra entender a lógica

Comment: Bah, não sei como te ajudar nisso. Talvez ler algum material mais avançado sobre linq seja uma boa ideia, mas eu não tenho nada pra te indicar.

Comment: blz, você pode me dizer o que significa essa linha: `Registro = procRegistro?.Registro ?? "Nulo"`

Comment: Posso. **`procRegistro?.Registro`** tenta acessar a propriedade `Registro` em `procRegistro`, porém, se `procRegistro` for `null` a expressão não vai estourar um erro (o que seria o comportamento padrão, sem usar o **`?`**), ao invés disso a expressão retorna **`null`**. Este operador se chama `null propagation operator`. Essa parte **`?? "Nulo"`** quer dizer que se o retorno da expressão à esquerda for **`null`**, ou seja, se `procRegistro` **ou** `procRegistro.Registro` for `null` o valor da expressão vai ser a literal `"Nulo"`.

Comment: Você pode ler sobre o primeiro operador em: [**O que é o operador “?.”?**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/18246). E sobre o segundo em [**Qual o significado do operador “??”**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/18246)