# Como tratar o NullReferenceException com o Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, reflexão, null

Tenho uma classe para fazer buscas pelo `DisplayName` das minhas entidades, onde passo a entidade e classe retorna uma lista com os valores e nome reais de cada atributo da entidade.

Meu problema em si é quando faço a busca e algum atributo na entidade não possui a anotação `DisplayName`. recebo o erro de `'System.NullReferenceException'`.

Eu tentei colocar `where` para quando encontrar algum valor `null` não listar, mas meu erro ocorre quando instancio o `DisplayName`:

```
.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName != null)
```

Como posso resolver esse problema? pois terei entidades com alguns atributos sem `displayname` e não quero que sejam selecionados.

Segue os códigos:

**PesquisaAvançada**

```
public class PesquisaAvancada
{
    public String Valor { get; set; }
    public String Texto { get; set; }

    public static List<PesquisaAvancada> camposPesquisa<T>()
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public |
                       BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName != null).
                                                                             Select(p => new PesquisaAvancada()
                                                                            {
                                                                                Valor = p.Name,
                                                                                Texto = p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName
                                                                            }).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Entidade Cliente**

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Identificador do Cliente")]
    public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    // aqui removi o display name e acusa o erro
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Nome Fantasia")]
    public String Fantasia { get; set; }
}
```

**Erro:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Model.dll

**Imagem para melhor entendimento:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que está ocorrendo é que você está tentando acessar uma propriedade de um objeto nulo

```
p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName != null
```

O certo é verificar se o `GetCustomAttribute` retorna um objeto válido, sendo assim a sua condição where fica:

```
.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()!= null)
```

No código acima todas as propriedade que possuem o atributo DisplayName são retornadas.

Comment: Certo Tiago entendi, mas na hora do `Select` busco novamente o `DisplayName` e irá ocorrer `NullReferenceException`. Como posso pegar o valor na variável texto? desse local: `Texto = p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName`

Comment: Depois que você fez esta condição where, terá uma coleção de `DisplayNameAttribute` que não são nulos, assim, você pode pegar a propriedade `DisplayName` no `Select`.

Answer (score 6):

É só usar o [`null-conditional operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) do C#.

Se o retorno de `p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()` for `null` não será feita a tentativa de acesso à propriedade `DisplayName` e o resultado será `null`.

```
.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName != null)
```

---

Duas perguntas que pode ser interessante dar uma olhada:

1. [O que é o operador "?."?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91785)
2. [Qual o significado do operador "??"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44133)

[Veja o exemplo abaixo funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LjeL5G)

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var customAttrName = GetCustomAttribute()?.DisplayName; 
        // Isto não estoura erro, ao invés disto, 'customAttrName' recebe null

        WriteLine(customAttrName ?? "Null"); //Null será a saída
    }

    public static CustomAttr GetCustomAttribute()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class CustomAttr
{
    public string Name;
    public string DisplayName;
}
```

Comment: O _downvoter_ pode me dizer o que está errado na resposta pra que eu possa arrumar?

Comment: Engraçado esses downvoter sem justificativa, poderia ter um meio de evitar isso; Downvoter só ser valido com um comentário justificando e etc...

Comment: É, mas é complicado. Isso já foi bastante discutido aqui no site, mas realmente é uma situação bem delicada. De qualquer forma, eu aguardo _feedback_ pra poder arrumar a resposta.

Comment: @jbueno entendi sua colocação, quando coloco o operado `?` não consigo encontrar mais o atributo disponível `DisplayName` utilizando o comando Ctrl+Espaço.
`.Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>()?.DisplayName != null)`

OBS: não fui eu que negativei sua resposta. Agradeço a ajuda

Comment: @Aprendiz Qual a versão da linguagem que você está usando?

Answer (score 1):

Esse DisplayName retorna uma string ou estou enganado ?

Tenta substituir:

```
p => p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName != null
```

por:

```
p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty( p.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>().DisplayName));
```

Comment: Ainda assim vai ser feita uma tentativa de acesso a um membro no retorno nulo. O que vai estourar um erro.