# Como converter um int nullable para int comum

Tags: c#, conversão-de-tipo, null, nullable

Eu tenho um método que recebe um inteiro que pode ser `null`, caso for acontecem algumas execuções de métodos, porém quando vou usar essa mesma variável em um lugar que usa `int` que não pode ser nulo, aparece que o `overload` está incorreto.

Então gostaria de saber como posso fazer essa conversão, existe algum método que faça isso como `ToString`?

Código com o problema

```
public HttpResponseMessage Metodo(int? variavel = chamadademetodo.metodo {

            if (variavel == null) {
                ...
            }

            var bla2= blablabla.metodo(variavel, DataContext); //aqui acusa problema
}
```

Comment: `variavel = chamadademetodo.metodo` isso não existe.

Comment: @bigown não existe, foi só para usar de exemplo

Comment: Fico pensando se você realmente precisa desse `int?` aí.

Comment: @bigown preciso, esse app também é mobile e caso o int não for nullable , pode interferir no comportamento to app

Comment: Tudo o que você fizer pode afetar o funcionamento, mas boa parte das coisas pode ser feito de uma forma melhor. Assim como você pode usar o `dynamic` (na sua pergunta anterior), tem jeito melhor, esse é um caso que pode ser que tenha solução melhor.

Comment: entendo, talvez exista forma melhor, porém isso envolveria mexer em muito lugares e/ou exigir conhecimento que não tenho ainda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você também pode usar:

```
int variavelNNula = variavel.GetValueOrDefault();
```

No caso o default de int seria zero.

Answer (score 5):

Normalmente, a técnica a seguir resolve:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Metodo(int? variavel)
{
    var variavelNaoNula = variavel ?? 0;

    var bla2= blablabla.Metodo(variavelNaoNula, DataContext);
}
```

Comment: para que serve os "??"

Comment: É um operador chamado coalescência. Se o lado esquerdo é nulo, atribui o lado direito.

Comment: @Paz https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101, não para este caso, mas também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101

Comment: sensacional, valeu @bigown

Comment: valeu pela explicação @CiganoMorrisonMendez