# FirstOrDefault, SingleOrDefault, ElementAtOrDefault

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Qual a diferença entre os elementos `FirstOrDefault` e `First`, `SingleOrDefault` e `Single` ou `ElementAtOrDefault` ou `ElementAt`. Quando utilizar com e sem o `Default`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As versões sem o `Default` geram exceção se encontrar zero elementos no critério adotado, então ele deve ser usado quando há certeza que tem pelo menos um elemento. Ou seja, se tiver zero elementos é um erro de programação e deve ser corrigido ou é algo excepcional e deve ser tratado (mais raro do que maioria imagina).

Com o `Default` ele retornará o [valor padrão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default) do que o tipo espera se não achar nada, e obviamente não gera exceção. Pode até ser um `null` se for tipos por referência, mas pode ser um valor zero em outro tipos. Ou seja, é esperado que venha "nada" e isto deve ser tratado posteriormente, provavelmente com um `if` ou equivalente, algo como o [`??`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44133/101) ou [`?.`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101).

Comment: o que seria o valor padrão? Não seira um  NULL?

Comment: Botei um *link*, não necessariamente nulo, pode ser um 0.

Comment: legal @bigown vou olhar com calma o link!

Answer (score 3):

Simples, o uso do Default retorna um valor NULL caso não tenha resultados... enquanto o outro dá um erro se não existir e for usado.

Use sempre com Default e faça uma validação com IF antes de usar, minha sugestão:

```
var obj = lista.Where(x => x.valor = valorProcurado).FirstOrDefault();
if (obj != null) 
{
    //Executa ações
};
```