# Diferença em cast usando "as" e "type cast"

Tags: c#, .net, cast

Surgiu uma dúvida sobre *casting* em C#, vejo em muitos fonte usando o *cast* das seguintes formas.

Qual a diferença dentre um e outro, quando usar de uma forma ou de outra?

```
public interface InterfaceTeste
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClasseTeste : InterfaceTeste
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class ClasseTestando
{
    public void Teste()
    {
        List<InterfaceTeste> objList = new List<InterfaceTeste>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 0; i++)
        {
            objList.Add(new ClasseTeste() { Id = i, Nome = "Nome" + 1 });
        }
        ClasseTeste classe1 = objList.Find(x => x.Id == 1) as ClasseTeste;
        ClasseTeste classe2 = (ClasseTeste)objList.Find(x => x.Id == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quando você faz a conversão utilizando "as", caso o código não consigo fazer a conversão retornado um valor nulo e quando você faz a cast normal se o programa não conseguir fazer a conversão será retornado uma exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nesse exemplo nenhum dos dois é necessário, portanto, não faz diferença.

## `as`

O operador `as` deve ser usado quando você não tem muita certeza que a operação dará certo. Considere que haverá uma tentativa de conversão, mas se falhar o objeto que deveria receber o valor daquele tipo receberá o valor nulo. Depois de usar o `as` é essencialmente obrigatório verificar se o objeto não é nulo. Então você faria. Se não está fazendo essa verificação provavelmente não precisava desse *casting*, ou terá um outro erro mais pra frente, o que pode ser um problema maior descobrir o que está acontecendo.

O custo desse operador `as` é até menor, mas quando fazemos a verificação se ele não é nulo acaba ficando mais ou menos a mesma coisa.

#### C# 6

Normalmente você faria um `if` para verificar se o valor é nulo para decidir o que fazer. [Em C# 6 existe um operador que não faz nada se for nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91785/101). Em alguns casos é possível usá-lo para simplificar o código, mas não em todos.

#### C# 7

É possível usar [*pattern matching*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) e só criar um novo objeto quando confirma que o tipo do objeto é aquele esperado.

#### C# 8

Nessa versão que não incentiva mais o uso de tipos nulos, portanto o `as` deveria cair em desuso e dar lugar ao ao *pattern matching*. O *cast* com parênteses ainda será útil.

## *Cast*

O *cast* clássico, o segundo, exige que você tenha certeza absoluta que a "conversão" não falhará. Qualquer situação que você saberá que ela não falhará você pode usá-lo. Em muitos casos o custo de usá-la é zero.

Uma das formas de ter certeza absoluta é fazer um `if` antes de fazer o *cast*, mas se fizer isso é porque deveria usar o `as`. Tenha certeza mesmo, se precisa verificar é porque não a tem. Se fizer isso a performance será pior e poderá entrar em [*race condition*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

Esse é um caso que você só está informando para o compilador que você pode garantir que o tipo é aquele que o compilador espera. Se a sua garantia não se conformar em tempo de execução a aplicação lançará uma exceção que não deve ser tratada, isto é um erro de programação e deve consertar este erro.

Ele tem ainda a vantagem de fazer conversões em tipo por valor. Esses tipos não podem ser nulos, então o `as` não funcionaria. Claro que não inclui os tipos por valor anuláveis.

Ele pode fazer conversões de tipo quando ela é implementada no próprio tipo. O operador `()` pode ser implementado nos tipos para conversão explícita (também é possível de forma implícita onde um operador não é usado). O `as` só é permitido onde a linguagem deixa naturalmente, em conversões naturais, em geral apenas fazendo um tipo derivado se transformar em um tipo base dele.

Não vou afirmar que nunca seja necessário, mas para futuro eu esqueceria o `as`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Quando você faz um cast com o operador `()`, se a conversão falhar será retornada uma exceção do tipo `InvalidCastException`. Já quando a palavra-chave `as` é usada, se a conversão falhar o resultado será `null`. Por isso a palavra-chave `as` só pode ser usada com tipos de referência ou tipos *nullable*.

Veja os seguintes links:

> Diferença entre cast e as - C#
>   https://cbsa.com.br/post/diferenca-entre-cast-e-as---c.aspx
>
> as (Referência de C#)
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as
>
> Operador () (Referência de C#)
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/invocation-operator
>
> Conversões cast e conversões de tipo (Guia de Programação em C#)
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

E, a partir do C# 7, também é possível usar a palavra-chave `is`, tanto para testar o tipo quanto para fazer uma conversão, dessa forma:

```
string s = null;
if (objList.Find(x => x.Id == 1) is ClasseTeste ct)
{
   s = $"Id: {ct.Id}, Nome: {ct.Nome}";
}
```

> is (Referência de C#)
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is