# O que significa (Char)0 / (Char)8 / (Char)13?

Tags: c#, .net, char, cast

Estou fazendo um programa de compras e achei na nesse mesmo site. A resposta para um problema que tinha, mas não entendi o que seria a parte `(Char)0`, entre outras. Preciso de explicação o que é isto.

```
private void preVenda_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && 
         e.KeyChar != ',' && e.KeyChar != '.' && 
         e.KeyChar != (char)13 && e.KeyChar != (char)8)
    {
        e.KeyChar = (char)0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '.' || e.KeyChar == ',')
        {
            if (!preVenda.Text.Contains(','))
            {
                e.KeyChar = ',';
            }
            else
            {
                e.KeyChar = (char)0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Segue a imagem:

[image: Código]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E isso você entende?

```
'\0', '\8', '\13'
```

É a mesma coisa. Tudo é número no computador. O tipo `char` é apenas algo que conceitualmente é tratado com "letras" (caracteres) e quando você manda mostrar já é desenhado como texto, mas a codificação de cada caractere é um número seguindo uma tabela. C# usa por padrão a codificação UTF-16, mas o grosso dos caracteres que usamos são da [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), então cada número se refere a um caractere, e nem todos são imprimíveis, alguns são especiais e mandam fazer alguma ação específica ou determinam algo que não é imprimível, que é o caso de todos abaixo do código 32.

O `0` é nulo, o `8` é uma tabulação e o `13` é uma mudança de linha. A barra invertida é um caractere de escape, na sintaxe de boa parte das linguagens, incluindo C#, ele indica que o que vem a seguir algo especial e não deve ser tratado como caractere e sim como um código da tabela de codificação ou até algum termo especial, por exemplo o 8 pode ser expressado como `\t` e o 13 como `\r`, ou em alguns casos como `\n`, mas aí depende de plataforma. É necessário fazer assim justamente porque eles não são imprimíveis.

Como C# é uma linguagem de tipagem forte ela evita misturar tipos e fazer promoções automáticas que podem dar algum problema, então você não pode atribuir números ou usar como operando de `char` diretamente, você tem que garantir explicitamente que que o tipo sendo usado é um `char`, por isso é feito um [*cast*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286192/101) no número só para afirmar para o compilador que você sabe o que está fazendo e aquele número deve ser interpretado como caractere.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).