# Converter dynamic para outro tipo

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, dynamic

Eu preciso converter uma variável do tipo dynamic para outro tipo em runtime.
O tipo que quero converter está armazenado em uma outra variável (Eu não sei qual o tipo em tempo de desenvolvimento).

Tem algo parecido com isso?

```
dynamic dynamicVar = 3;
string tipo = "double";
var valor = MetodoQueConverte(dynamicVar,tipo ) ;
```

O código acima é um resumo do que estou fazendo.
O *MetodoQueConverte()* é só um exemplo do que preciso, ele não precisa existir.
Por exemplo, a variável *dynamicVar* vai ficar com o tipo int nesse caso, porém preciso armazená-la em outro lugar como double.

Eu preciso fazer uma conversão com base em um tipo que está armazenado como string em outra variável.

Comment: Cara, não consegui entender a sua pergunta e nem o código apresentado. Mostre um exemplo, não tem nada de dinâmico e sem ver o `MetodoQueConverte()` não dá pra fazer ideia do que você está tentando. Tente editar a pergunta fornecendo um [MCVE]

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286192/101

Comment: Essa pergunta não deveria ser fechada, porque realmente tem um classe no C# que faz esses tipos de conversões, não é `cast`

Comment: Bruno seja mais claro esse tipo dinâmico ficou estranho na sua pergunta coloque o valor desse dynamicVar!

Comment: Melhorei a descrição.