# Valor NULL em banco de dados x performance

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, null

Sempre usei banco de dados (MySQL) pra pequenos projetos e nunca me importei com a opção "NULL quando for vazio", ou seja, ficava em branco mesmo.

Agora estou projetando um sistema grande, gostaria de saber o conceito de usar o valor `NULL` quando o campo estiver em branco, pra que serve, qual vantagem e ou desvantagens etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em consultas SQL, o NULL se comporta de forma diferente ao utilizar determinadas funções, ex:

Uma tabela com:

`| ID | Cliente | Valor Gasto |
| 01 | JOAO    | 100         |
| 02 | PEDRO   | NULL        |
| 03 | MARIA   | 50          |`

Ao executar

```
SELECT SUM(Valor_Gasto) * 100 / COUNT(ID) FROM tabela
SELECT SUM(Valor_Gasto) * 100 / COUNT(Valor_Gasto) FROM tabela
```

Na primeira query COUNT é igual a 3 e você recebe o valor 50, já na segunda COUNT é igual a 2 e você recebe 75, pois null é ignorado na contagem.

Nada demais, mas dependendo de como deseja calcular, isto evita utilizar uma validação no WHERE.

Ou quando você faz validação com <> (diferente de) ou IS NOT, ex:

```
SELECT Cliente FROM tabela WHERE Valor_Gasto <> 50
```

Isto traria penas o Joao, pois o Pedro tem valor NULL, teria que tratar a coluna ou usar uma função que considere o nulo, não sei para todas as linguagens mas no Postgres pode usar:

```
SELECT Cliente FROM tabela WHERE Valor_Gasto IS DISTINCT FROM 50
```

OU (esse acho que é universal)

```
SELECT Cliente FROM tabela WHERE COALESCE(Valor_Gasto,0) <> 50
```

Na query acima ele troca o NULL por 0, então o Valor Gasto nunca será NULL, espero ter ajudado de alguma forma

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro leia a [pergunta que fala sobre NULL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90363/101). Use-o do jeito certo. NULL é NULL, vazio é vazio. NULL indica a indeterminação do valor.

Teria que medir se tem alguma diferença de performance em várias situações. Posso quase garantir que não tem nada perceptível. O que pode causar algum problema, mas não muito grande se usar ou deixar de usar equivocadamente. Mesmo assim será um efeito colateral. Não se preocupe com a performance, faça o correto, dê a semântica adequada para o dado.

Só deve usar ele onde você pode ter valores indeterminados naquela coluna. Por padrão é melhor que a coluna não aceite NULL, porque é ideal que não exista valores indeterminados. Mas frequentemente o ideal não se encaixa na realidade e temos que usá-lo.