# Consulta SQL apenas para registros não nulos

Tags: sql

Eu tenho uma tabela `NotasFiscais` e estou buscando todos os registros que contém na coluna `NChave`. Porém alguns resultado contém essas informações e, outros não, no caso estão como `NULL`. Como eu poderia trazer apenas registros 'verdadeiros' ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Null não é um valor, precisa usar `IS NULL` para achar nulos ou `IS NOT NULL` para não nulos na hora da comparação. Deve ficar algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM NotasFiscais WHERE NChave IS NOT NULL
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[O que realmente significa NULL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90363/91)

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela orientação. E sua indicação atendeu à minha necessidade.

Comment: @IgorCarreiro não esqueça de marcar esta resposta como solucionadora do seu problema.

Answer (score 5):

Null é um resultado que não retorna valor algum por isto não pode ser comparado por operadores como = ou !=,
para isso você deve usar `IS NULL` para encontrar valores NULL e `IS NOT NULL` para encontrar valores que não são NULL.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IS NOT NULL
```