# Existe alguma regra para "declarações de tipo em propriedades de classe"?

Tags: php, tipagem, null, psr

O PHP 7.4 dá suporte para [declarações de tipos em propriedades de classe](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php).

Em uma rotina normal eu usaria:

```
/* @var array */
protected $names;
```

Agora no PHP 7.4 eu posso:

```
protected array $names;
```

Porém se eu declarar desta forma que está eu não consigo inicializar ela como `null`, eu teria que fazer:

```
protected ?array $names = null;
```

É errado fazer isso?

Em uma classe com muitas propriedades posso declarar o tipo em todas as propriedades?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim e não.

Se existe a *feature* então pode usar. Mas não use onde não precisa.

Bem, a questão é muito mais complicada que isto. Entra na filosofia de PHP, ou a falta de.

Sim, PHP tem sofrido de falta de personalidade. Essa é uma das maiores críticas que as pessoas que entendem de linguagem de programação fazem ao PHP.

PHP era uma linguagem de [tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) simples e sem cerimônia, fantástica para fazer *scripts* para web. Um belo dia resolveram que ela deveria se transformar em uma linguagem *enterprise* para criar sites complexos. Ótimo, certo? É tudo o que as pessoas podem querer.

Parece, mas na verdade uma linguagem não muda assim tão fortemente, especialmente não muda na parte que ela usa tipagem fraca que é o real problema da tipagem da linguagem. Tipagem dinâmica não é um grande problema, embora não facilite tanto a [escala de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364945/101) tudo funciona bem e dá uma flexibilidade bastante interessante.

Quando PHP começou pôr força no tipo ela criou classes, interfaces (especialmente esta que só serve para tipar) e traits, permitiu colocar o tipo do dado cada vez em mais lugares, ainda que no fundo o tipo continue dinâmico internamente.

Uma classe, em PHP, ainda não é um tipo estático real internamente, mas estão tentando fazer parecer assim. A linguagem ainda não tem [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) que é obrigação de qualquer linguagem que tente se mostrar estática. Mas alguma coisa me diz que criarão, nem que seja o jeito errado fazendo isto:

[image: Quebra cabeças em relevo de letras de borracha com peças forçadas no lugar errado]

#### Nulo faz sentido?

Outro ponto que quebra a tipagem estática é a nulidade do tipo. Em linguagens realmente estáticas permitir que um [valor nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90363/101) seja um dado aceito é como se o dado pudesse ter dois tipos. De fato as linguagens mais modernas estão evitando o nulo, o chamado erro de um bilhão de dólares, pelo menos por padrão e você ter que dizer que o nulo é um valor válido quando realmente quer o nulo. Mas como é um erro deveria usar nunca... **em uma linguagem de tipagem estática**.

[image: I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the null reference in 1965]

Me desculpe se isto te irrita, mas PHP está se tornando uma aberração de linguagem, algo bem esquizofrênico. Ainda é uma linguagem útil, dá para fazer muita coisa, mas nem dá para dizer o que é certo ou erro fazer nela.

Claramente está sendo conduzida por pessoas que parecem crianças em uma loja de brinquedos que querem ter tudo o que vê pela frente e copiam tudo o que tem nas outras linguagens mesmo que não faça sentido na delas.

[image: Veruca Salt]

Então você tem que decidir o que vai fazer, vai usar o brinquedo ou não?

Em outra linguagem ele faz muito sentido, mas em PHP a tipagem ainda é dinâmica e isso não faz muito sentido. Mas ela está permitindo fazer.

Se vai adotar a ilusão de tipagem estática deve evitar o nulo, o que pode ser uma boa porque vai que um dia eles quebrem a compatibilidade da linguagem e torne de tipagem estática, você já está no caminho certo. Duvido que aconteça, mas claramente ela ficou com uma inveja tremenda de [Hack](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143708/101) e quer ser ela, só que não quer perder os usuários que já tem, que são muitos.

O erro de Hack foi querer ser uma linguagem bem feita e incompatível (ainda com uma sintaxe de varável horrível e sem sentido).

Eu recomendaria sempre evitar o nulo a quase qualquer custo. Ele é ruim conforme já mostrado, e tem *links* sobre. Em algumas linguagens permitir o nulo é a quebra que mais acontece. Não é fantástico se for impossível ele acontecer e ele já ser pego?

Claro que não ajuda tanto o fato da linguagem não ser compilada, então o erro ainda será pego durante a execução, portanto a vantagem não é grande. Você só pode confiar 100% se fizer um código de cobertura de 100%, o que as pessoas costumam dizer que dá trabalho demais e em grande parte das vezes não conseguirá. Enquanto PHP não for compilada, de verdade, não apenas JITtada, a vantagem será bem menor.

Mas dizer que a semântica daquele dado não pode aceitar nulo é uma boa, porque em geral é um acidente a linguagem permitir o nulo em todos os casos.

Mesmo as linguagens que não aceitam nulo de forma correta ainda costumam permitir você optar pelo tipo ser anulável, porque tem caso que isso faz sentido. Em um bom *design* é extremamente raro, mas sempre tem, muitas vezes por causa de banco de dados (que também pode ser evitado com bom *design*, mas pode ser difícil demais e até criar problemas de performance, então nem sempre compensa fazer).

## Finalmente o que quer saber

Seu *array* aí pode ser nulo? Por que? Qual a vantagem? Sabe de todos os problemas que isso pode dar por poder ser nulo? Pra que iniciar algo como nulo?

Pra mim a solução é não inicializar a propriedade como nula, o correto é colocar um *array* vazio ou com dados ali na [construção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) dele. Isso serve para a maioria dos casos. Se seguir todos *links* entenderá melhor.

Só não sei como isso conversará bem com o resto do seu código. Fará todo código pensando nisso? Usará só bibliotecas que usaram assim? É extremamente difícil, pra não dizer impossível, fazer código legado que o padrão era anulável com um novo que o padrão não é. Se começar permitir o `?` em todos tipos para poder comunicar bem com outros códigos, onde o padrão é aceitar nulo, então perde o motivo de usar isso. Mas isso vale não só para o nulo, para qualquer coisa que envolva tipo.

Eu acho que você deveria optar por um jeito ou outro em 100% do código, ou adota a tipagem ou não adota. Se não adotar então não faz sentido usar classes, interfaces e outros mecanismos que serve para organizar mais o tipo. Se adotar, não faça pela metade, adote a não nulidade por padrão, só aceite nulo se não tiver outro jeito melhor (não posso garantir se o seu caso dá para ficar sem.

Na outra resposta mostra um caso que pode ser interessante o tipo aceitar nulo. De fato não é ruim, internamente você garante que o dado só será acessado corretamente e [não vaza abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101). Mas saiba que tem como fazer aquilo sem o nulo. Tem que criar uma variável que controle se o objeto está inicializado ou não. É melhor assim? Não sei, mas é uma opção que não é ruim. Por outro lado nada impede inicializar o objeto antes e ele sempre estar disponível nem ter que controlar se já foi inicializado ou não, por alguma razão algumas pessoas acham que não pode.

Eu não adotaria a tentativa de tipagem estática justamente porque nunca ficará bom em linguagem de tipagem dinâmica. Mas isso é causa perdida, os programadores PHP decidiram que vão seguir receitas de bolo em vez de pensar sobre o que estão fazendo.

## Conclusão

Pra mim é uma boa *feature* e força o programador ser melhor, pensar mais no *design*, começar fazer o que é certo e não apenas o que funciona que é o padrão de muito programador PHP

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

O problema é que PHP quer ser Java ou C#. Então porque não usar essas linguagens que são mais adequadas para o que ela quer ser? Essas linguagens foram pensadas para serem *enterprise*, se quer uma linguagem assim vai para uma que seja assim desde sua concepção.

De outra forma, só faz sentido usar o PHP do jeito que ele foi concebido originalmente. A forma como as pessoas estão optando por fazer no PHP, porque a linguagem tem permitido cada vez mais ser assim, acaba ficando com o pior dos dois mundos quando está tentando ter o melhor dos dois mundos. Você não consegue ter todas vantagens de tudo, e quando não opta por qual quer ter fica algo ruim. E PHP não tem mais como optar por ser *enterprise* do jeito certo, só se for outra linguagem, como fez Hack.

Então as pessoas adotam a linguagem por motivos falaciosos. Nenhum problema em adotar PHP, mas precisa saber porque está fazendo isso. As pessoas que buscam essa nova PHP se dariam melhor com outra linguagem, mas o efeito religioso que ocorre com a maioria das pessoas elas não conseguem reconhecer isso e vão sofrer pro resto da vida.

Esses dias vi um vídeo de defesa de linguagem que era cheio de falsidades sem dizer uma mentira sequer. Tudo para parecer neutro e encantar as pessoas "mostrando" como aquela linguagem era maravilhosa, mesmo todo mundo que entende do assunto dizendo o contrário.

[image: Símbolos religiosos]

Então pense bem o que você quer para você. Se vai começar usar tipos, e eu gosto disto, use de forma correta, aprenda programar corretamente (PHP acostuma mal as pessoas) e comece dar a semântica correta, não use nulo onde não precisa.

Eu não posso falar se esse caso precisa do nulo, eu acho que não, mas não posso afirmar, só dá para responder isso com um caso concreto. Uma das coisas que as pessoas não entendem, especialmente quando faz OOP, é que dar a semântica correta é o mais desejável e mais difícil de fazer. Quase ninguém sabe fazer certo, e novamente, fica com o pior dos mundos, cria a burocracia de usar um código cheio de firulas e não tem um *design* bom porque ela não entende o que de fato é desenvolver software. E isso envolve não acreditar que uma receita de bolo serve para todos os casos. Desenvolver software é tomar decisões certas em cada mínimo detalhe do processo, e para isto é preciso profundo conhecimento de todos aspectos da computação.

Se cansou de ler isso talvez não goste da área que demanda muito esforço das pessoas para fazer certo.

Por outro lado se não liga para isso, e não parece o caso do AP, pode fazer de qualquer jeito que funcionará, pelo menos aparentemente.

Eu não conheço os detalhes, imagino que para isso fazer algum sentido tem que configurar algo que dê algum erro quando tenta usar um nulo quando não pode. E não sei como fica a interoperabilidade com código que não usa essa forma.

Nenhum problema a pessoa programar em PHP, mas para usar a linguagem corretamente como ela se tornou, a pessoa teria melhores benefícios com outra linguagem.

[image: Carro com um cavalo dentro com a cabeça pra fora]

Eu não gosto muito de usar a frase "a ferramenta certa para a tarefa" porque a maioria das ferramentas funcionam bem para vários problemas, mas esse é um caso que na forma usada parece a ferramenta errada, porque tem uma melhor para fazer assim. Está usando algo que era um martelo e ia bem com pregos e agora está tentando ir bem com parafusos. Tente usar isto:

[image: Um tipo de canivete suíço com machado, martelo, etc.]

[Falei mais sobre isso no Quora](https://pt.quora.com/unanswered/Quais-s%C3%A3o-os-defeitos-que-a-vers%C3%A3o-atual-do-PHP-ainda-tem).

Ah, quase sempre usar algo `protected` é um erro, junto com nulo tende ser pior.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bom, eu não vou discordar de nada achei a resposta bem elaborada e pensada... Quanto ao uso da propriedade ser `null` é que ela só se torna um array quando eu executo um outro método, caso contrário ela nem é inicializada, `protected array $names = []` seria uma boa? Eu estou no ramo do PHP faz 7 anos e sempre tentei seguir o que a documentação diz, ou as normas `PSR`. Mas, Mineiro, não entendi se você odeia o PHP ou se só acha ela ruim mesmo haha. Na sua opinião o Python é boa linguagem para aplicações web? Devo migrar? Ou apenas estudo o PHP mais a fundo para melhorar o jeito que eu utilizo?

Comment: **"Em outra linguagem ele faz muito sentido, mas em PHP a tipagem ainda é dinâmica"** Algum dia irão fortalecer a tipagem do PHP?

Comment: `ela só se torna um array quando eu executo um outro método` provavelmente erro de *design*, mas não posso afirmar sem conhecer o caso concreto.. Eu não odeio linguagem alguma, e já usei muitas, eu gosto de estudar o assunto, não sou só usuário de linguagens. Eu odeio fanatismo por linguagem, qualquer uma. PHP é uma das linguagens, que hoje, no passado não era assim, tem defeito demais. Eu não estou dizendo que deve mudar de linguagem. Você só trocará de problema. Nem que deve continuar com PHP. Não deixe as pessoas dizerem o que você deve fazer. Sempre deve estudar qualquer coisa a fundo...

Comment: ...só assim poderá tomar decisões certas por conta própria. Tipagem dinâmica e fraca são duas coisas completamente diferentes, coloquei *links* sobre isso, mas eu sei que quase ninguém clica, as pessoas não gostam de aprofundar os estudos e se aprendeu errado ficará errado pra sempre. PHP não pode ter tipagem forte sem quebrar todos os códigos existentes. Mesmo a tipagem estática ele pode ter mas fica mais ou menos incompatível o os códigos que usam a tipagem dinâmica que é prevalente em quase todos os códigos existentes hoje.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, irei ver os links que você citou, estudarei mais a fundo, se surgir alguma dúvida eu comento aqui ou abro outra pergunta se for o caso.

Comment: @TioGê isso, assim que funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Uma contribuição menos completa que a do Maniero, mas que acredito que deve ser levada em conta. Caso se deseje evitar idas indesejadas ao banco de dados, pode ser utilizado o famigerado **singleton**, não vou entrar nos detalhes e discussões a respeito de que deve ser evitado ou não.
Especificamente neste caso, imaginemos um método get que vai preencher e retornar o valor de um atributo, conforme abaixo:

```
private ?array $names = null;

public function getNames()
{
    if ($this->names === null) {
        $this->names = NamesDAO::retornaArrayAposConsultaOnerosa($this->outroAtributoQualquer);
    }

    return $this->names;
}
```

`private ?array $names = null;` passa a fazer sentido, pois esse atributo sendo nulo simplifica a verificação utilizada no método. Caso ele fosse declarado como `private array $names = [];`, A verificação de que o acesso ao banco já foi feita não seria tão simples, pois `NamesDAO::retornaArrayAposConsultaOnerosa($this->outroAtributoQualquer);` retorna sempre um array, que pode ser vazio.

`private array $names = [];` é a opção mais adequada para os demais casos, pois você não vai precisar ficar verificando se é um array para fazer um foreach por exemplo.