# "Erro" referente ao ponto de interrogação (?) usado em declarações de funções PHP

Tags: php

Pouco tempo atrás, estava fazendo um curso de uma playlist do youtube..

E, estava indo tudo ok.. até que.. deparei com o ponto de interrogação, onde o autor usava nas funções.

No meu caso dava erro e nas aulas estava tudo ok, tanto que o autor nem fazia referência a esse ponto.

Se eu tirasse o ponto de interrogação, não dava erro. Mas fiquei na dúvida de.. se fazer isso o código iria ter algum comportamento diferente do autor, ou não.

Então desanimei.. e fui fazer outra coisa! Mas.. queria retornar ao curso.. pq o conteúdo era interessante.. por isso o pedido de ajuda aqui.

Um exemplo de onde o autor aplicou a interrogação:

```
public static function getString(): ?string { .. }
```

Só o fato de ele colocar o `" : ?string "` já achei estranho, pq até então não havia me deparado com códigos fizessem dessa forma!

Já vi em outras linguagens, mas no PHP ainda não havia visto. Então creio que ele está "forçando" a função a retornar um valor String, caso contrário irá dar erro. Até aí tudo bem, mas.. o que significa essa interrogação antes da "string " ??!!!!

Outro exemplo dele:

```
public function find(?string $terms = null): ?DataLayer
{ .. }
```

Neste último ainda usa dentro dos colchetes de parâmetros.

Não tenho agora o erro que me gerou, pois "abandonei" o curso!!

Mas, uma ajudinha e explicação a respeito ajudaria.

Li algo a respeito, aqui no fórum mesmo, de algo parecido mas era usando Laravel, e uma das respostas dizia o seguinte:

> A versão não corresponde ao novo recurso que se chama Nullable types
>   que foi introduzido na versão 7.1, então a 7.0 não tem esse recurso
>   por isso dos erros.

Se for alguma incompatibilidade do PHP, não sei dizer.. mas estou utilizando o PHP 7.4.4.

Enfim.. fico no aguardo de alguma ajuda.

Obrigado.

Comment: O ponto de interrogação `?string` diz que a função pode retornar uma string ou um valor `null`. Quando é usada em atribuição `?string $var = null` diz que a variável pode receber um valor null ou uma string.

Comment: [Aqui está uma reposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438511/existe-alguma-regra-para-declara%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-tipo-em-propriedades-de-classe) bacana feita pelo @Mineiro, recomendo a leitura pra tomar cuidado com esse tipo de atribuição.

Comment: Referente a "operador ternário".. eu sei como funciona. E.. isso não é operador ternário!!
Só se for algo "novo" e não sei.


@Boi Programador, essa sua resposta é exatamente o que eu tinha em mente!!!
Mas ainda permanece a minha dúvida!!
Que é o por que o PHP não está reconhecendo???


Obs.:.. marcaram como "duplicada", mas não encontrei algo a respeito.. da forma que me é o erro!!..
A maioria que encontrei se referia a operador ternário!!
De qualquer forma, vou continuar procurando.. pq ainda tenho o problema!!
Obrigado..

Comment: Pra te dar uma resposta precisaria do erro exato que ocorreu, mas eu posso chutar apenas uma possível causa do erro: A versão do seu PHP, esse tipo de declaração de retorno e atribuição só é possível a partir da versão 7 do PHP. Quanto a esse retorno `?DataLayer` parece ser o retorno de uma instância da própria classe, precisaria de mais informações na sua pergunta pra conseguirmos elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: @ Boi Programado.. 
Entendi.

O "erro" não foi exatamente referente ao "DataLayer", até pq.. isso faz parte do código criado pelo autor.

O que eu estava fazendo.. para seguir com o curso dele, foi.. retirar essa interrogação.

Mas não acredito ser a melhor forma.

Vou retomar o curso e posto a mensagem de erro que php retorna.

Mas, o php não está reconhecendo nada do uso da interrogação!!

Exceto ao que se refere a ternário, que não tem a ver com o caso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Se você está retirando o `?` e está funcionando é pq a função não retornou valor `null`. Algum momento ela retornará `null` e seu código gerará um erro.

Comment: criei um exemplo no [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gVEPGZmS), dá uma olhada lá.

Comment: Ok.. vou ver.. e testar.. Obrigado.